# Closed vote invalidated before triggering review

Tags: bug, closing

I recently voted to closed several questions as duplicates: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223377/f-defined-fx-fy-leq-x-y1-alpha-prove-that-f-is-a-constan), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970008/why-is-the-holder-space-with-exponent-alpha1-a-constant-set), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214830/given-fx-fy-leq-7x-y2-show-f-is-a-constant-function) and [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537216/proving-a-function-is-constant-under-certain-conditions).

Somehow they have different fate: and first and the fourth one got into the review queue, and the fourth closed (by a gold-badger).

The second and third one, if I understand correctly, are not yet in the review queue. Actually I doubt if they will: my closed vote have already been invalidated (see their timeline [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2214830/timeline), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/970008/timeline))

That seems to be a bug (at least a wrong feature). It is fine that closed vote are invalidated after the review are completed (like those in the first question, somehow it is not shown in the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1223377/timeline) that the votes are gone). But if it is invalidated before triggering a review, then there is no way an individual user can trigger a closing (without putting it in CRUDE for example).

Comment: I'd guess that the close votes in this case aged away. It happens either after 4 days or after 14 days, depending on number of the view, see [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) and also [How do close votes age away?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136989)

Comment: This is not related to your main question, but since both examples were duplicate close votes, I'll mention existence of [The duplicate thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24972).

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSleziak Somehow I forget about that thread. I'will put those questions into that thread.

Comment: To confirm what @MartinSleziak said, it aged away. (As an aside, Aged away votes can be recast after some time.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. The votes aged away, as suggested by Martin.

For all I can tell, the questions were in the review queue. It is just that no one reviewed them. See the review-reports:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/972835
- https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/972837

Once the one vote had aged away, they got removed from the queue. 
Of course it is not ideal that no one reviewed them. But this seems like a separate issue.