Surrendering to the duplicate flood
You may have noticed that I have been quite active recently flagging duplicates, but also asking users to respect the site guideline to not post answers to duplicate questions. I am not sure if I can continue doing that since basically I have the feeling that it doesn't help. Even experienced users just ignore this, or are just unwilling to use the site search (let alone the OPs).
Just to mention one example from today.
Block components corresponding to $A : V \oplus W \to V \oplus W$
Absolutely standard linear algebra question. Duplicate for sure. Also no clear effort from the OP, by the way.
But within minutes, two answers by two users arrive. The one user has rep of 5k and is here since 6 years. The other user has a rep of 62k and is here since 6 years. For sure they know how the site works. They just ignore it.
Of course we could follow the usual procedure of closing the question as a duplicate (finding some exact duplicates is an easy exercise when you know how to use site search), and you could ask the two users to not answer duplicate questions. When users repeatedly violate the guidelines and don't change their behavior after referring them to the guideline, we are encouraged to flag one of their answers. But does this change anything? Personally, I think it is just a drop in the ocean.

Question. Is that usual procedure sufficient to reduce or even prevent answers to duplicate questions? Does it implement MSE's quality standards in an effective way?

Notice that I am not talking about that specific question only. It is just one example of many duplicates that appear every day. Here is another example just a day later:
If $T$ has finite dimensional range so does $T^*$
Clearly a standard question, and with approach0 I could easily find three duplicate targets (maybe there are more, but that was enough). But the question received two answers by users with 44k and 176k rep. They didn't even bother to use site search. I don't want to call out these specific users. It won't bring much. The problem is bigger.
Even worse:
To prove $A\cup\emptyset=A$, is it necessary to discuss separate cases of $A$ being empty or non-empty?
No idea why you could get the idea that this obvious duplicate deserves an(other) answer? 4 answers posted by users with reputation 464k, 103k, 12k, 45. With approach0 I could locate 5 duplicate targets. The question has been closed and even deleted later.
I suspect this topic has come up multiple times on meta already. But I am not convinced that a suitable solution has been found and implemented so far. And to be honest I also need to vent a bit about it. Maybe the answer is also that, unfortunately, we have to accept some duplicates answers (for now).
For example, I could today post a question why $A \cup B = B \cup A$ is true, write something so that it doesn't look like a PSQ, probably receive some answer in the comments, and the moderators and more engaged users then have to "clean up the mess" afterwards: find a duplicate target, gather enough close votes, tell users to not answer duplicate questions, etc. But why do we even allow these questions when they have been answered already 10 times?
Based on this, I wonder if we should take a more "radical" (=attacking the root cause) approach:

Question. Are there ideas how we can site-wide prevent duplicate questions in the first place?

Here is a very rough idea: We use AI to facilitate the manual process of finding duplicates. Specifically, some kind of AI always checks if a new question is likely a duplicate by checking the existing questions within the same topic. Every elementary question is marked as likely duplicate anyway: an AI should be able to detect this confidently. When a question is detected a likely duplicate, it's not published directly: instead someone with a corresponding privilege needs to manually check the question and compare it with the duplicates found by the AI (if any came up). If they confirm it's not a duplicate question, only then it will be published. This way, we will prevent a lot of duplicate questions on this site. Just to clarify: I am only asking if AI can support our manual process, it should not decide anything. Therefore, even though AI currently is probably not perfect at detecting likely duplicates, I suspect it can simplify the review process.
Let me give an analogy. When you go to a concert, you are not allowed to bring your own drinks (at least here in Germany). You have to buy them at the venue. If you bring drinks, you need to empty or throw them away at the entrance, otherwise security won't let you pass. Now imagine... this check doesn't happen at the entrance. There are posters telling everyone to not bring any drinks. Some follow this rule, but most people don't, in fact many haven't seen these posters at all. Security checks some people after they have already entered the venue if they have brought drinks. But they cannot possibly check everyone. Doesn't make any sense, right? Well this is how MSE is currently handling bringing duplicates to this site.
PS. This is not a duplicate of this question since there it was mainly about high rep users (but the problem is clearly about all users, above I only used them to make sure that they actually know how the site works) and was about an explanation why this is happening. I don't ask for an explanation. I am asking how we can prevent this from happening in the first place, and also if the current procedure to deal with duplicates is sufficient with regards to the mentioned site guideline of MSE and hence of the site's quality overall.

It can work if enough users contribute to site organization, e.g. a few users have made great progress in the last couple years handling duplication in elementary-number-theory.  To succeed in more massive tags like calculus will likely require diamond mod cooperation - i.e. EOQS warnings and suspensions for repeated dupe violations (which will only happen if the community helps by flagging frequent offenders).  Thanks for recently joining the crusade.

Worth mention: the data explorer can be used to locate users who answer many PSQs & dupes, e.g. here is the query I used to attempt to help vet mod candidates in the prior election. Perhaps diamond mods or the smoke detector could regularly run a similar query to help locate the worst offenders so that we can nudge them to reform. That might go a long way towards slowing down the flood.

Culprit here, and first time on meta (I wish it was under more pleasant circumstances). Prior to answering I did search for “block decomposition direct sum” and briefly looked through the first 50 out of 163 hits, and for the most part they don’t explain the notation (and now looking over the remaining hits, that seems to be the general trend… because indeed it is a simple linear algebra matter). Also, I looked at OP’s profile and they know about vector bundles and stuff, so I figured I might as well answer the trivial question about notation itself, to get it out of the unanswered pile.

But clearly I missed this answer (albeit to a completely unrelated question, and mild reversal of indices) else I would have linked to it in a comment. I’m extremely careful when asking my questions, but in light of this post, I can definitely be much more ‘active’ prior to answering as well.

So we agree that, in the "block component" example, you have to be more knowledgeable than the OP to find the duplicate (I can't find it). Then why is it so important that OP is punished by not getting an answer? If it's not about punishment, then why is a closed question with helpful answers worse than a closed question with no answers?

@Stefan Those "helpful" answers are almost always dupes. Rampant duplication (esp. of common exercises) makes it difficult if not impossible to weed through search results to  locate the "best" answers, and wastes precious community time vetting the  new dupe answers (when instead that time could be spent iteratively refining the existing dupes into "proofs from the book"). Remember the charter of the site is to be an easily searchable library of high-quality Q&A's. It fails miserably if it is not easily searchable (and/or devolves into an ephemeral stream of low-quality fgitw answers).

@BillDubuque You can exclude them by typing in "duplicate:no" with your search. (For some reason that also excludes all answers.) But actually my solution to all those problems would be to delete questions with a delay (say 10 days) instead of closing them. Then the people who just want to help can do so in peace, without making life harder for those who want to build a library.

@Stefan Constraining SE searches via duplicate:no doesn't remedy all of the issues I mentioned. Deleting with a delay still wastes community effort - time spent posting and vetting answers that will soon be deleted. Such time would be better spent iteratively improving the canonical dupe answers, and better organizing them.  Posting (fgitw) dupe answers is usually not "helping" since it often deters questioners from visiting the canonical dupe thread - which usually has better answers that have been vetted and improved over many years.

I think one difficulty is that very often, the setting in an old question does not properly match the setting in the new one. Marking such a question as a duplicate target of the new one may be confusing, esp. to novices. This is actually the case in the $T^\ast$ question Martin linked to: the lin. map in the closed question is between two different infinite-dimensional inner product spaces, but the map in the alleged duplicate target is an operator on one finite-dimensional space. To be frank, I would say that this is not a “high quality closure”.

"...idea: AI always checks..." - instant -1 from me. AI absolutely cannot reliably tell elementary questions from advanced ones. Even experienced users on this site often get that wrong. And assuming a question is a duplicate just because it's elementary? Come on. All this will just add more noise into the system than duplicate questions do, while also opening the thin end of the wedge for AI integration with this site, which people have fought so strongly against.

Anyway, if you want to resolve the duplicate problem, surely the solution is to make the duplicates easier to find, by the OP as well as reviewers. AI probably could help with this, since in my experience it's quite good with the kind of "reverse lookup" type problem from the question in the OP, where you explain a concept and it tells you the right search terms. A system where AI suggests possible duplicates based on more than just text matches would be much more sane than one where AI gets to flag things.

It is worth mentioning how difficult it can be finding a duplicate even with approach0. I've come across many questions I know have answers on this site already, but finding them is an absolute pain. Sequences could be $a_n$ or $x_n$. Searching specific functions isn't great, especially for common functions and trying all variations of variables for them ($x$, $t$, $s$, $z$). I think it's not necessarily worth the headache of trying to find duplicates for something that isn't a proof type question where keywords can help you out.

@Stefan Vetting (analysis and critique) of posts via votes, comments, links, etc is essential to the success of the site. Vetting the many tens if not hundreds of dupes of common exercises adds up to much wasted community time. As you say, it is your prerogative to waste your time as you like posting dupes. But please keep in mind that doing so ends up wasting the time of many others too, due to the extra effort  involved in vetting, closing, linking, etc when processing duplicates (and the extra work involved when processing longer lists of search results).

@Cameron TIP Every time you post a Q/A you should ensure that it can be easily located by obvious simple searches. If not then add some keywords, phrases etc that help in that regard (and improve tags, titles, etc). This goes  a long way towards making duplicate targets easier to find. I've been doing this for decades (even in prior platforms like sci.math). It works quite well.

This post is itself (ironically) a duplicate, or nearly so: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32941 . I echo my comments from there: what is the incentive to find duplicates? There is no reputation, no badges, and no real acknowledgement for the effort. On the other hand, posting an answer that is largely the same as one you've already posted is easy and will often get some upvotes.

New users should be instructed to take their time and browse the site with the search facility before they decide to write down a question. Duplicates and arbitrary musings produce "garbage" (in computer technology terms).

This question is similar to: Why do high rep, long time users answer duplicate or too similar questions on book recommendations?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have seen the other question, and it's a different one. Not sure why people see this as a duplicate. Indeed both questions are about users answering duplicate questions. But my question is not about finding reasons why this is happening, it is about finding ways to prevent this. I have made a short edit.

@xsnl I think you misunderstood Viktor's (valuable) comment. I will try to explain it with my own words. Lots of work on MSE is rewarded with reputation points, badges, statistics on the profile page. But currently, finding duplicate targets and simlar work isn't rewarded at all in this way. From an idealistic POV, indeed you are "rewarded" with MSE becoming slowly better, but this is not incentive to work on this aspect. Most people only want to answer questions quickly and don't care about the overall quality of the site. Maybe they change when there is a badge for duplicate target work.

@Martin Does your AI method think the meta question you ask here is likely a dupe?  Further, can it do a dupe analysis on Viktor's proposed dupe, proving it can do better than the $19$ human upvoters who apparently do believe Viktor's incorrect duplication claim?

On a side note: I think you commented on an answer that I once posted to a close (not exact, as I recall, but close) duplicate. You may have also down-voted the answer; I don't recall that. As a single data point, I didn't ignore that, nor did I resent it. I agree with the basic aim, and would like to be more vigilant about that. I have to admit, though, that I don't have that mental check in my routine yet. I suspect the duplicate was in the suggested related questions in the sidebar, and I wonder if it would help if that list were somehow more prominent when one answers a question.

I'm intrigued by the idea of using AI to find duplicates. ChatGPT is not ideally designed for this, but based on your evidence it seems at least useful; perhaps LLM adapted as a classification algorithm would be even better. I note that some general web search algorithms are trending in that direction, and they can be instructed to search only this site.
I also agree that it is better to flag duplicates and put new answers (if any are desired) under the already-answered questions so that answers are collocated. I try to do this, although I am not as diligent about it as you are.
Aside from lack of attention, I see two major problems in the quest to properly identify duplicate questions on this site:
First, as things are right now, the duplicates are often not easy to find. On various occasions I've seen questions that I'm almost sure were duplicates, but I've been unable to find the questions they duplicate. Approach0 can help, but sometimes the question is not primarily about a particular formula. Keywords may have far too many hits and far too many synonyms to be sure that the question you're looking for is even in the 100 responses returned by the search engine.
Second, there is the question of what actually makes a duplicate.
Case in point, your example:
To prove $A\cup\emptyset=A$, is it necessary to discuss separate cases of $A$ being empty or non-empty?
(Full disclosure: I'm one of the users who answered this question, although I later deleted my answer.)
In this question, OP already had a valid proof of the statement. (The proof was given only in a comment and only after prompting, so that's a serious flaw in the presentation of the question; nevertheless, OP clearly did not need someone else to provide a proof.) So the question really is entirely about whether $A=\emptyset$ needs to be treated as a special case.
Now, surely the question of how to prove $A\cup\emptyset=A$ is a basic question that one would expect to find already on the site. In fact, you found the following:

A question that presented an attempted proof that $A \cup\varnothing = A$ and $A \cap\varnothing = \varnothing$ for verification.

A question that asked how to prove $A \cup\varnothing = A$ and $A \cap\varnothing = \varnothing$ with no effort shown in the question.

A question from someone who read the previous question and its answers but wanted to know, "How does a truth statement (a sentence in Englisch) just translates into a set inclusion??"

A question that raised the point, "you have to assume that $x\in \emptyset$ but this is against the definition of empty set."


To me, it is clear as day that none of the first three questions duplicates the one I answered. The doubts expressed by the OP of that question could just as easily be raised after reading any of those pages. (The doubts are mistaken and easily answered, but they were presumably real in the mind of OP.)
The bit about $x\in \emptyset$ in the fourth question reminded  me of what happens when $A = \emptyset$ and was sufficient to prompt me to delete my answer and vote to close the question instead, citing the fourth question as the duplicate.
I'm not so sure about this "duplicate" any more. It now seems to me that the "duplicate" may have been about a different detail of a proof in which $x\in \emptyset$ again makes an appearance. But I don't feel strongly enough about this to attempt to undelete and reopen the question.

To be clear, I was happy to see the question about "$A$ being empty" linked to all of the "duplicate" questions, because someone who found this question as the result of a search is more likely to really want to see one of the other questions.
But just as there is a need to address the quality of questions on the site, there is also a need to address the quality of "duplicate" closings. Posting three "duplicates" that never even come close to the key point of the question is counterproductive; it just encourages people to oppose your attempt to mark the question as a duplicate.
A better approach, I think, would be to post all the not-quite-duplicate questions as cross-references in one or more comments under the question.
I also wouldn't object to someone commenting on an answer I wrote, "Did you check to see whether this question was a duplicate before answering?" Some of us (myself included) could use a reminder like that from time to time.

Let me repeat my comment from the link. When in a linked dupe a proof without case distinction (empty or not) is given, it does answer the question if a case distinction is necessary or not (of course, it's not). A similar example: Let's assume someone asks if in the claim that subgroups of solvable groups are solvable one needs a case distinction if the subgroup is trivial or not. (Yes, stupid question, but notice the similarity.) We should definitely close this as a duplicate and use one of the questions where the usual proof is given that doesn't use this weird case distinction. 1/2

Not only gives this the OP the best understanding of the proof, but it also avoids spamming MSE with all sorts of questions which bring no value at all. The product of two spaces is compact, do I need an extra case where one space is empty? The union of two bounded subsets is bounded, do I need an extra case where one of the sets is empty? etc. I think we should definitely close these as duplicates. 2/2

+1, especially for "just as there is a need to address the quality of questions on the site, there is also a need to address the quality of 'duplicate' closings." No matter how the duplicate issue ends up being addressed we should be trying to do both those things, not just the first - this is really crucial.

On that topic I'll repeat what I said in comment under another answer, now moved to chat. This site has a very nice agreed policy on duplicates at Coping with abstract duplicate questions and its top answer, and that policy is not that we should always close question A as a duplicate of question B if an answer to B suffices to answer A. Obviously questions often should be closed in that situation, but not always, and the actual policy on this is quite nuanced.

It's also well worth reading this official SE post. It's quite nicely written and nuanced. The tl;dr is that it matters what the question was, not just what the answers are.

@MartinBrandenburg Your arguments are mathematically sound, but they treat MSE as a site only for people who have the mathematical maturity to fully understand them. This site is not just a "junior MathOverflow." We also explain things to people who are not yet trained mathematicians. And if that means we have to explain over and over, in one proof after another, why this or that special case is not actually special, that's just part of the deal, at least when we encounter an OP (as in this case) who knows how to write the proof without cases but still doesn't understand why this is OK.

I'm turning my comments into an answer as requested. Note, I've reformulated this a couple of times since posting, you can see the previous versions in the edit history.

...idea: AI always checks...  Every elementary question (an AI should be able to detect this confidently) is marked as likely duplicate anyway

I agree that the duplicate flood is a problem and in principle I'm not against using AI to help solve it, but I really think this particular suggestion is a terrible idea. I understand the suggestion to be:

the AI looks at each question and judges whether it's likely to be a duplicate or not, based only on the question text without checking for duplicates, as detailed in a previous revision of the OP's answer, where an example prompt is given.
these then go into a queue of "probable duplicates".
high-rep users and/or mods go through this queue and manually search for duplicate questions, voting to close if they find one.

I think this is a bad plan for two reasons.
Firstly, I find it pretty objectionable to maintain a queue of questions that are considered "probable duplicates" without actually searching for duplicate questions, regardless of whether such a queue is populated by AI or by humans. Of course certain kinds of question are more likely to be duplicates than others, but whether a question is a duplicate or not depends solely on whether a duplicate question exists. Of course high-rep users use their intuitions to judge whether a question is likely to be a duplicate before searching for one, but I don't think it makes sense to formalise that process. It just means you'll have a queue of very noisy data, consisting of questions where someone (or ChatGPT) felt they "looked like duplicates" even though they might very well not be. Such questions would be likely to end up closed even if they aren't actually duplicates at all. This would lead to more questions being closed, but not necessarily the right ones, and I think this would drive down the signal-to-noise ratio in an unhelpful way.
Independently of that, I think judging a question's probability of being a duplicate is a task that ChatGPT and its ilk would be absolutely terrible at. I guarantee there will be some kinds of questions that cause it to say "wow, what a great question, this is very original" even though they've been asked dozens of times, and other kinds of question that make it say "this is very basic and likely to be a duplicate" even if they're not. An LLM has no memory outside of its context, so where these biases exist they will be persistent - it's not capable of learning from what it's seen before. Such biases will be hard to detect because the technology is unpredictable and non-transparent, and they will also be exploitable if users learn to phrase questions in the right way to please the AI.
On the other hand, while I'm very much against this particular suggestion, I do think there are ways in which AI could be used productively to help resolve the "duplicate flood". If the AI is involved in actually searching for duplicates instead of just judging questions based on their text then its output will contain useful information and not just vibes. If it's done right that should decrease the signal-to-noise ratio in question closures rather than increase it.
In my experience, LLMs are quite good at "reverse look-up" problems where you describe a concept and it suggests relevant search terms. As the comments below this answer suggest, that could be used to improve the list of related questions, and that by itself could make a huge difference. It would not only make the reviewers' work easier but it would also make it easier for people to find the answer to their question before asking it, and thus not post a duplicate question in the first place.

You may have misread my idea. The AI only detects likely duplicates. The actual decision if it's a duplicate is made manually by someone with a corresponding privilege or moderator role. I am not saying that AI single-handedly should close questions as duplicates. The reviewers need to find duplicate targets or, if some have been found, take the ones suggested by the AI. I suggest that you edit the first paragraphs of your answer accordingly as it currently is a strawman. I will also make a separate answer where I analyse if ChatGPT can detect likely duplicates in a good way.

Summary: AI should facilitate the current duplicate hunt, not replace it. Basically what you already wrote in your last paragraph, but I suggest to do this already before the question is published (to reduce the flood).

@MartinBrandenburg I'm sorry, but if the AI is taking the first step, of flagging it as a likely duplicate, then everything I say in this answer stands. And your question definitely does say you want the AI to be doing that. It says it in the part I quoted.

This is so regardless of whether the AI's flags are actual close votes or special AI flags that put it in a separate queue of AI flagged questions. Either way, people who like closing questions are going to go through that list and close them without really checking if they are exact duplicates or not. This is because that's how humans behave. It will be correct most of the time, so why bother checking? But it won't always be correct, so we'd just be replacing human judgment with AI slop.

@Martin A less aggressive form if AI integration: use AI to improve the list of "Related" questions. This may make it much easier for the OP or others to find good dupe targets. Additionally SE should extend its built-in search tool to use this AI integration to find "related" questions (and to generate pertinent tags, and better questions of "interest" to users based on their history).

Indeed, the "related questions" are my first go-to when I consider whether a question is a duplicate. When the list is good, it tends to lead to a duplicate pretty quickly, either in the original list or in another "related" list of a promising link. Anything that would improve the relevance of that list would be a huge benefit.

I think the problem is even worse than it seems since we have many shadow duplicates, by which I mean duplicate questions that get some answer(s), the OP is happy, question is solved, but nobody really checks if it was a duplicate in the first place.
To evaluate this, I have looked at the 10 most recent new questions and did a a manual duplicate hunt with site search and approach0. In this sample, I found 60% duplicates (and maybe more, see below).
My personal interpretation is that, as mentioned, the current moderation after publication approach is simply not working. It does not stop the flood of duplicates. I think that some moderation before publication becomes necessary to stop it, and maybe AI can help us with that, maybe not.
To clarify: with duplicate I don't mean that it's the same question, but rather that the question has been answered in one of the answers in or even just the question body of the original question.

Question 1 ❌
What is type of probability is involved when mathematicians say, eg, "The Collatz conjecture is probably true"?
Duplicate of Is there such a thing as proof by example (not counter example)
I have added the duplicate, but 3 answers were already posted. (There is nothing wrong about these answers, but they just should have been posted in the original question to organize the site better.)
Question 2 (TBC)
Sampling with replacement, odds of being selected twice. Why is my solution wrong?
This is not my area of mathematics, can someone else look?
Question 3 (TBC)
What are partitions of unity in surface integrals for?
This is not my area of mathematics, can someone else look?
Question 4 ❌
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5016507
Duplicate of $f$ measurable implies $\dfrac{1}{f}$ measurable and many, many others
I have added the duplicate. The question has been answered in the comments, sigh ...
Question 5 (TBC)
Trigonometry with complex numbers
I only found the converse at If $\cos(z-x) + \cos(y-z) + \cos(x-y) = -\frac{3}{2}$, then $\sin x + \sin y + \sin z = 0 = \cos x + \cos y + \cos z $. (multiple times, actually).
I would be surprised if this is not a duplicate. Maybe someone can help? But as someone wrote in the comments: There is really no incentive for this, already 2 answers arrived, OP is happy, ...
Question 6 ❌
How do Unicode's ("Mathematical") "Flattened Parenthesis" and "Angle Bracket" symbols differ?
We have is there a convention of the usage of square brackets and round brackets? and Angle brackets for tuples and ...
It's an obvious duplicate, and I have added it. Nevertheless, 2 answers have been posted by high rep users.
Question 7 ✅
What is meant by Weyl's test for straightness of a line? Is this a problem of translation from the German original?
I think that this is a new question!
Question 8 ❌
Ultrafilters in posets
This is a duplicate of I don"t understand the definition of principal ultrafilter (but closed as PSQ)
Question 9 ❌
I've been analyzing $\int\frac{1}{x^n-1}dx$ for a while but I have a few questions about it.
Duplicate of Does closed-form expression exist for integral $\int \frac{dx}{1-x^n}$ and several others
I have added the duplicate, but already one answer has been posted. It was closed afterwards, and then heavily edited by the OP, so please check the history.
Question 10 ❌
A question about notation with a functional equation
Duplicate of Notation for iterating functions (already closed as such by Xander before I looked)

In a previous version of this answer, I also talked about ChatGPT, but I have removed this for several reasons. A better pre-analysis needs to be done with an LLM that is fed with all prior SE questions.

Question 1 and its supposed duplicate are asking about similar topics, but if you read what they're asking they clearly aren't the same question at all. I think this illustrates very well the problem with this whole "I've decided this is a duplicate on the basis of vibes, now let's find something to close it as a duplicate of" approach.

And again, I don't think I'm misinterpreting your idea. You want AI to flag questions as possible duplicates based on your intuition that it can pick up a general vibe of duplicateyness from the question text alone, without looking for duplicates. Then you have the idea, which I think is mistaken, that humans would carefully check those flags before acting on them. That you want to do this is stated very explicitly in your question and it's also literally what you put into your test prompt in this answer.

This doesn't really seem at all helpful to me.  So what if GPT outputs "the question is likely a duplicate"?  This doesn't help anyone to find a duplicate question, nor do I believe that GPT is even a reliable predictor of whether or not a question is a duplicate in the first place.  "AI" tools for detecting duplicates will only ever be useful if they can forward potential duplicate candidates.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
