# Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 01/2022 - today)

Tags: discussion, re-open, big-list, undeletion

The purpose of this thread is to focus the attention of the community on posts that may require reopen and undeletion votes. A request should be posted as an answer below (one request per answer).

Some guidelines:

- Please be polite, and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community. Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on site policy or other contentious matters. That should be done in a separate linked thread. The goal is to keep this meta thread free of tension, so that everyone feels comfortable posting here.
- There is a reopen queue. Please wait until a post has gone through this queue, before posting here. Notice that the first edit after the question may push the question into the reopen review queue if the edit is done within 5 days of closure The question will only be added to the queue if you check the box to indicate that the question's original close reason has been addressed. And one can also use a reopen vote. (If the review has already been finished, it is shown on the [timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24826/how-to-see-questions-time-line) of the question.) When in doubt, wait 24 hours after the last substantive action.
- To inform readers of the current (and past) states of the targeted post, please add the information  **Reopened** or **Undeleted** at the start *once the request has resulted in some action*. (If the action is undone, add this too, like **Reopened, Reclosed**.)
- Do not only post a request, like "request reopening of `link`". Instead, make a case for your concern. Yet keep in mind that it can be easier to get your request handled if you try to frame it in a way that takes the feedback the post received into account positively rather then seeking confrontation. Also, try to improve the post before posting here.
- In case of "small" requests, like one missing vote, it can make sense to ask in chat instead of posting here. The room [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured) is a reasonable place for such requests. The same guidelines apply there.
- If you are involved in the thread which you post about (e.g., you asked the question or you answered it), please disclose this.
- Please do not (vote to) delete answers to this thread unless there are serious problems.

---

Earlier versions of the thread that served as a model:

- [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 01/2021 - 12/2021)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32975)
- [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - 12/2020)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692)
- [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 01/2015 - 07/2018)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042)
- [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc. (volume 10/2012 - 12/2014)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424)

Comment: Creating a new thread is unnecessary and **bad idea**, e.g. see [here and its links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-12-2021#comment160037_32975)

Comment: I applaud annual lists, lest the lists of "answers" becomes difficult to navigate.  Also, @Paramanand, thanks for including the links to other "volumes", previously!

Comment: I'm sorry to be nitpicky about this, but the second bullet point may need some further tweaking. Rather than saying, "Notice that the first edit after the question may push the question into the reopen review queue if the edit is done within 5 days of closure...", it might be better to just say "Any question with significant edits that address the close reason(s) are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for reopening", which is the text in the corresponding [Help Center article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).

Comment: @BillDubuque My answer here that you said should not be deleted, was just deleted. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today/34878#34878

Comment: @Nick Flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @Bill, the answer on meta has now been deleted and locked by "Community" so it can no longer be flagged.

Comment: @Gerry the deleted answer is still flaggable for me. In any case one can raise the flag anywhere (e.g. on this question), and Nick has already done so (cf. Math Mods' Office chat).

Comment: Why is one user allowed to dominate this thread? If you look at the posts, and the requester who always gets their way, often after inappropriate edits to a poor question, there's a definite pattern of *dominance*.  And I say this only because mods have not yet intervened.  I'm surprised that the moderators keep turning their heads in silence and inaction, hence, giving free rein to one user.

Comment: @amW, anyone is allowed to post to this thread, and anyone is allowed to register disagreement with a requester. If other users disagreed with any one requester's posts, they could vote that user down, with no need for moderator intervention. And if other users haven't complained about one particular user, then I'd say the moderators are quite right not to intervene.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Not practically.  You play a huge role in that.

Comment: Not exactly a welcoming interaction here. Unbelievable. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616434/lectures-to-accompany-fraleigh

Comment: @Alper I just cast the last needed undelete vote to that posting, so now the posting has been undeleted.  However, just so you know, the posting is still closed.  I also cast a re-open vote for the posting.

Comment: @user2661923 that post was redeleted a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 14):

**Reopened**

[How do you find the center of a cake with just a knife?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400697/how-do-you-find-the-center-of-a-cake-with-just-a-knife) was closed as a duplicate of [Determine the centre of a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56457/determine-the-centre-of-a-circle) but it is **not** a duplicate. Cutting a cake with a knife is not the same thing as drawing lines with an unmarked straightedge; there are things you can do with the one that you can't do with the other. This was not made clear in the original posting of the problem, but it has been made abundantly clear with an edit. Please consider voting to reopen.

Comment: @amWhy, I will stand by my statement that you can do things with a knife and a cake that you can't do with an unmarked straightedge and a circle (and I'm not referring to eating). Did you look at the edit to the question? Did you understand the diagram there?

Comment: This is not small stuff, it's not splitting hairs, and it's not being contrarian. You can't find the center of a circle using just an unmarked straightedge, but you **can** find the center of a circular cake using just a knife. If you don't see how to do it, @amWhy, just take my word for it, it can be done.

Answer (score 8):

**[Undeleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4369765/timeline)**

Please vote for undeleting this question: [Bounds involving number of invariant factors and elementary divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369765). The question is interesting, and I provided the OP enough hints in order to solve it, so they could post an answer, or maybe someone else. This way other students will benefit from it.

*Last but not least, it was the asker that deleted their question, after helpful comments.*

Answer (score 7):

**Reopened**

[Why does $\Psi(n)=H_{n-1}-\gamma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310018/why-does-psin-h-n-1-gamma) has been closed as a duplicate of [Did I derive a new form of the gamma function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958762/did-i-derive-a-new-form-of-the-gamma-function). It is stated in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1959323) to the latter question that $\psi(n)=-\gamma+H_{n-1}$, but nowhere on that page is this equation proven.

I have written an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2310033/915354) to the question that was closed.

I really don't see how the former question is a duplicate of the latter. I think that "Why does $\Psi(n)=H_{n-1}-\gamma$" should be reopened.

Comment: Agree that it should be reopened.

Answer (score 7):

**[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4578212/timeline)**

Please consider reopening [least time to cross water swimming and running](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578212/least-time-to-cross-water-swimming-and-running). Someone asked in a comment if it was a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556636/what-is-the-minimum-time-to-get-from-x-to-q-on-a-circle-by-running-swimming-or), and I responded no — that question asks how to solve a textbook problem, while mine asks how to generalize that textbook problem. There were no further comments, yet my question was closed, and when I voted to reopen, it was closed again without further comment. I understand that I am supposed to edit my question in some way, but other than responding to the one comment already made, I really don't understand how I can make clearer that I am not looking for a solution to that textbook problem. It is impossible to ask my question without stating the textbook problem. If someone can indicate what is confusing about my wording that makes it seem like I am asking just for a solution of that textbook problem, I will be happy to edit.

Comment: There's nothing confusing about what you wrote; most users just don't read carefully.

Answer (score 6):

**Update: Question deleted, answer merged with another question's answers.**

Consider undeleting and reopening the question

[Growth rate of finite simple groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4046921/growth-rate-of-finite-simple-groups/4047533).

The question was sloppily written, but interesting. It was closed; later it was deleted by the system bot. For the record: I wrote an answer to the question, recording what I found in the literature. I also rewrote the question to make it more precise.

Edit: The original question was closed, due to lack of clarity. My edit aimed to improve clarity was rolled back to the original post, as written by OP.

Comment: Your edit was a complete rewrite, given you added context not provided by the OP.  If you feel strongly about asking a better question capturing the question you wish was asked, but was not asked, then post a new question to ask it.  That is okay to do; but it is not okay to transform a very poor post into a post that was not asked.  Ask it your self, instead, in a new post.

Comment: @amWhy: The essence of question is the same, the difference is the added background and a better formulation. But if the question does not get reopened, I will ask a new question myself.

Comment: The new question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4356284/growth-of-finite-simple-groups) (for those who are <10k). Not sure why there is an edit war on this post....

Comment: I did not intend to participate, and will not continue to edit this answer. I just wanted to make the update use the correct terminology and be more convenient to look at in the future with links. I apologise for any wrongdoings. For Math.SE users who do not know: [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question) is a link to meta.SE explaining what a merged question is, and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32402/) are the guidelines for context rewrites.

Answer (score 6):

**Reopened**

Request to reopen my question post ["What is the name of the symbol =
in English?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468328/what-is-the-name-of-the-symbol-in-english). It has been closed as a "Needs details or clarity" post. I clarified my question's distinction and submitted to review but not accepted as "Original close reason(s) were not resolved". I cannot understand or grasp the reviews' opinion or idea that they thought what is not clear.

Answer (score 6):

[**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1163545/timeline).

[Seven line segments, with lengths no greater than 10 inches, and no shorter than 1 inch, are given](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1163545/25554) asks a clear and straightforward mathematical question.  It was posted in 2015, and soon attracted several answers with net upvotes.  But recently it was closed and deleted for "lacking context".

The argument for requiring context is “by providing a context you help the potential responders to your question give you the best help you need.”  This argument is inapplicable to a seven-year-old question that already has several good-quality answers.

One of the stated purposes of the site is to be a permanent repository of mathematical questions and answers.  Deletion of old posts with good-quality answers is contrary to that purpose.  Deletion of this post makes the site less useful.

I suggest this post be undeleted.

Comment: Thanks for [reminding me](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163545/seven-line-segments-with-lengths-no-greater-than-10-inches-and-no-shorter-than#comment9127193_1163545).

Answer (score 6):

**Undeleted**

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4075052/121671) was posted in 2021 deleted by a moderator which prevents the community to cast votes for undeleting and/or reopening. I request that it is undeleted and reopened. The original complain from some users was that it was a question from the American Mathematical monthly (AMM)  in 2021. I think the posting is now old enough to be reconsidered for undeleting. It has an [answer](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Etauraso/AMM/AMM12247.pdf) in AMM, however, the answers given in MSE are relevant and some even different. To moderators, please considering bringing this posting back to MSE or at least let the community vote on this.

Comment: Alas, by SE design, only diamond moderators can undelete posts deleted by diamond mod's.  Btw, some users (not I) get really upset if you make such requests and don't explicitly disclose that you have answered the question (which is - of course - obvious to anyone who views it). Just letting you know to help avoid unwarranted downvotes.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Yes it is unfortunate, but that can be reversed too, although it takes a little more.

Comment: Since this request is directed to moderators and not to the rest of the membership, may I suggest it would be better posted to the moderators chatroom than here?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I understand that only a moderator can undo the deletion. My goal to post this request here first is so that the community know about this situation. I will post to the mods chatroom. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**[Undeleted, reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4333544/revisions)**

I asked about the cardinality of the space of functionals on square integrable functions, [Cardinality of the space of functionals on $L^2$ functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4333544)

I believe the question is a good on-topic question very similar to other questions about the cardinality of spaces of functions but new since it is about the cardinality of a space of functionals.

I believe the question was closed due to an initial error on my part in not including what I meant with $L^2$ functions. I have since clarified that I mean square integrable functions and have provided a link to its definition on wikipedia. A further comment asked $L^2$ functions on what space and I clarified I am interested in the cases $L^2(R^n)$ i.e. functions from $R^n \to R$.

I have tried reopening through editing and the undelete progress before but it somehow failed. (I don't believe I received any further comment explaining whether there was still an issue with the question). I still have the same question again months later and was about to write a similar question again when I remembered having asked this question before. So unfortunately for me etiquette requires I do not re-ask but instead try to get my question reopened.

Answer (score 5):

**Reopened**

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338301/localization-and-field) question has been closed on the grounds that if one read and understood a definition and some results from a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring), then one could construct an answer which uses the result proven in the answers to the associated question.

The question itself only involves basic ring theory, and the OP has made clear that they find the terminology in the wiki page and associated answer intimidating and prefer my direct answer.

I feel both answers have their merits, and it is not too hard to see that they essentially do the same thing, once you get past the terminology.  However the existence of an answer which uses another another answer, does not make a question a duplicate.

Comment: +1. OP explicitly states in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338301/localization-and-field#comment9418771_4338301) that "I have done only 1 course course in commutative algebra and you expect me to learn Von Neumann (regular) and regular rings. I am sorry these terms had nothing to do with my course. "

Comment: Such close is in the idea of this very old meta post: [Coping with abstract duplicate questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756). Nevertheless, [Arturo's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/coping-with-abstract-duplicate-questions#comment6091_1756) (emphasize mine) has yet to be addressed: "It would require the 'survivor variant' to have answers that **address both** the general strategy (so as to be useful for future minor variants) **and** specific application to the question at hand (which shows how the general strategy applies to a specific problem)."

Comment: The claims in the post above **grossly misrepresent** the matter. Please read all the comments on the question before voting. In fact  tkf's use of ultrafilters is surely more foreign to most comm. algebra beginners than is deriving the trivial needed consequences from the simple definition of von neumman regular rings. I fully support user26857's original dupe closure.  That the OP strangely does not want to read a simple one-line elementary definition does not mean that the question is not a dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes I agree the term 'ultrafilter' is as intimidating as 'Von Neumann (regular)'.  That is why I only mentioned the terminology incidentally, not as a core part of my answer.  I think you should give your solution as an answer, only mentioning the terminology 'Von Neumann (regular)' and the associated question incidentally, and repeating the argument from the associated post so your argument is self contained.  I would upvote such an answer and believe that it would have value complimentary to mine.  But the fact another answer could be given, is no reason to close the question.

Comment: That answer is already given in the linked dupe. It would be ridiculous to duplicate an answer simply because the OP refuses to read a simple definition - viz. a ring R is v.n. regular if for every element a in R there is an x in R with a = axa (true for fields: let x = 1/a  for nonzero a), and this property is clearly preserved in products of fields. That's all that one needs to know about v.n. regular rings to use the short simple proof in the dupe (which uses only basic comm. algebra and -further - gives simple *characterizations* of rings having the property studied by the OP).

Comment: I will have deleted the "Closed Reopened Closed" from the top of this post because that space is reserved for actions taken *after* the post is made here, not for the history of the question before the post here.

Answer (score 5):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening the following:

[Let $K=F_q(T)$ and $L$ be the spiliting field of the polynomial $p(x)=Tx+x^q+T^q x^{q^2}$ over $K$. Find the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495334/find-operatornamegall-k-where-k-f-qt-and-l-is-the-spiliting-field).

Was a PSQ, but the OP provided quite some context in the comment and also in the answer they later posted.

Comment: Rather, Arctic Char improved the question, hence Artic's request to open his question.

Answer (score 5):

**Undeleted, reopened**

Please consider undeleting and reopening [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4665649/any-hyperbolic-automorphism-of-mathbbtn-is-mixing).

I think the OP had provided enough context (reference, definitions, etc.) and they have self-answered the question.

The [reopen review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1943813) is just completed and it didn't go well.

Comment: Looks to me like it has been reopened.

Answer (score 5):

**Re-opened**

[HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/160157/442) is one.  It came to the front page again today.

Over the years, many posts have asked this same question: compute $\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{1+x^4}$ .  They have all been merged into *this* one.

It should be reopened.  It can serve as the target for any future duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

**Undeleted**

Please vote for undeleting this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1933337/121097. It is correct, and for some reason that I don't know it was downvoted twice, and this probably determined the answerer to delete it.

You can also upvote it, since it is way simpler than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4488118/timeline)

I would like to ask for this question to be reopened: [Polyhedron with only π/4 dihedral angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488118/polyhedron-with-only-%cf%80-4-dihedral-angles). I think there has been plenty context provided; the OP is responsive in comments and has clearly given it a fair shake; the question has been received well (6 votes). At the very least, it would be nice to understand why some think it should be closed. It has already failed to pass the reopen queue once.

Comment: I found it somewhat difficult to visualize the angles (e.g. how the "bowtie" is an example of what is described) but I put that down to my own poor geometric positioning rather than a lack of explanation. I voted to reopen (and voted the question up).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer its [this bowtie with the same vertices as a square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVV97.png) (hence a 'square bowtie')

Comment: (After breaking my head trying to understand that diagram for about $5$ minutes and then finally getting it) AHA! NOW I SEE IT! This question is just difficult to visualize, really, it's not lacking context or anything. If anything, feel free to add the diagram as a context edit. It cleared everything up for me. (Actually, perhaps I could get it from the older image as well, so this is just a "me" problem).

Comment: I did not vote to close the question, but I do not understand how interior angles are defined in the case of non-embedded polyhedra (OP did not respond). For instance, consider the case of a polyhedral Klein bottle in $R^3$....

Comment: I added the image. @MoisheKohan yes, though what you said wasn't phrased as a question, and your implication to not consider such shapes seems obvious. (also, is that from a conversation that is partially removed?)

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I do not understand what you are saying. Do you understand the definition of an interior angle for non-embedded polyhedra? An image (whatever it may be) is not a definition.

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry, the image is unrelated to you, but I didn't want to litter the comments section with two comments. I am essentially agreeing with you

Answer (score 4):

**Reopened**

Please reopen [How come area of all discs in $W=\left( 1-\dfrac{\pi}{4} \right) (1-\epsilon) (a-\epsilon)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603767/how-come-area-of-all-discs-in-w-left-1-dfrac-pi4-right-1-epsilon-a). It has been edited suitably, and I am not sure why it was closed in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening [Circle tangent to rotated ellipse and horizontal line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783381/circle-tangent-to-rotated-ellipse-and-horizontal-line).  It seems to me that questions like these are one of the ideal purposes of this site: someone has a math question that they need an answer to for some application (not just some homework exercise they want someone to answer for them) but which is beyond their knowledge.  It's not clear to me what additional context anyone would want beyond what has already been provided.

Answer (score 4):

**Undeleted**

The answer by Damien D to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986105/reference-request-federer-besicovitch-structure-theorem/4574290#4574290) question about the Besicovitch-Federer theorem on unrectifiable sets should be undeleted. The reason for the deletion was completely bogus, it is listed as "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes." - a boiler-plate comment that clearly does not apply to a published book reference. The proof of Theorem 18.1 (part 2), which is Besicovitch-Federer theorem, is quite long and involved, and there is no way one can provide "essential parts" of it in an MSE answer.

Remark: It is possible that Mattila's book "Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean Spaces" (from 1999) is not recent enough to OP's taste, but this is for the OP to decide.

Comment: I agree that this should be reopened, but it still should be improved by, for example, saying "...where the entire theorem is proven". "The proof of Theorem 18.1 (part 2)" could also be mentioned. [I'm happy to do these edits, but don't have access to the book so would just be going by your post here.]

Comment: @user1729: I edited the answer.

Comment: I can believe the proof occupies most of its chapter, but surely the statement of the cited Theorem (together with essential setup and definitions) is not too much to ask for an Answer on Math.SE.

Comment: @hardmath: OP knows the statement and the setup and was asking for a reference to a detailed proof.

Answer (score 3):

**Re-opened**

[Proving Wolstenholme's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4417540/proving-wolstenholmes-theorem) has been closed as a duplicate of [Proof of Wolstenholme's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325491/proof-of-wolstenholmes-theorem). However, the supposed duplicate asks not for a proof, but what is wrong with their proof.

The mistakes made in the proof seem easy enough to make, and would be instructive to others, in my opinion.

Comment: Perhaps this should be re-titled, e.g. "What's the mistake in my proof of Wolstenholme's Theorem?"

Answer (score 3):

[**Undeleted**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3739092/timeline)

Please vote for undelete the following answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739092/121097

I have added the relevant information required in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

**Reopened**

I posted this question: [Optimal path on the surface of cuboid doesn't visit the same face twice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470117/optimal-path-on-the-surface-of-cuboid-doesnt-visit-the-same-face-twice). It was a simple one and someone answered it as a comment. I was planning to expand on the comment and post an answer. This would have been useful for my future reference. However, the question was closed. I'd like to appeal this. Just because its a simple question doesn't mean it can't be useful. The reason says "it doesn't have context". But I feel its completely self-contained and additional context is unnecessary. In any case, I have added it in an edit.

Comment: "Just because its a simple question doesn't mean it can't be useful" and just because it's useful (no evidence given for that) doesn't mean it should be open. Reviewers (and commenters in this case) attempted to ask for some kind of information or elicit some effort out of you , likely because they felt the need to do so instead of answer directly. The link provided is good enough ,in my eyes, for context. Note that "structured optimization" (optimal controls having specific properties) is a big deal in research, and this is a toy example.

Answer (score 3):

Update: **This Question has been undeleted and reopened.**

1. A newcomer, unschooled in [Mathematical English](https://abstractmath.org/MM/MMMathEnglish.htm#:%7E:text=Mathematical%20English%20is%20a%20special,English%20is%20a%20foreign%20language.),
   posts this *reasonable* and *natural*
   [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4484146/21813):

   - Since there is actually **exactly one** dog, why do we still say that there is "some" (i.e., at least one) dog?

     *In general*, how do I know when "some" means **at least one**,
     and when it means **exactly one**?

   My Answer explains that even when we know that there's exactly one
   dog, it is *not wrong* to state that there is "some" (i.e., at least
   one) dog, and that, in many contexts (for example, existence
   proofs), not only is the latter formulation sufficiently precise, it
   even makes our work easier.
2. The Question was **closed for lacking details/clarity**, and
   subsequently deleted.

   I am requesting undeletion on the grounds that **the Question** is legitimate, **feels so natural that it is likely useful to future readers in the same shoes**, and
   certainly not an incoherent rubbishy piece of site clutter.

   (And while it is short and inherently reflects the fuzziness of the
   OP's crystallisation process, it clearly encapsulates the OP's
   points of confusion; expanding it to give the semblance of fuller
   context would just be pointless verbiage.)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of a [more general question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/402020/).    "Reasonable" and "natural" are not, in-and-of-themselves, sufficient reasons to retain a question.  "Novel" is also required.

Comment: If it's a duplicate, I'd suggest it should be closed (and deleted) as a duplicate, rather than with the notice "This question needs details or clarity."

Comment: "A newcomer, unschooled in mathematical vocabulary and arguments ... " Obviously, this "context" you mentioned is either being ignored or regarded as useless by the second comment above.

Comment: @XanderHenderson My undelete request's thesis question is regarding **the confusion over multiple interpretations of For Some**, whereas your linked question is asking about **the difference between For All and For Any**, so both questions (each is a good FAQ) in fact cleanly complement each other.

Comment: Your misunderstanding was due to the latter's inaccurate title and irrelevant cursory side-mention of For Some, and the former's similar irrelevant cursory side-mention of For All & Any. (Yes, neither author is a particularly good writer, and I've just edited the latter, for clarity.) $\quad$ Also, note that *the two post's Answers do not at all cross-address each other's Questions.* $\quad$ (ping @GerryMyerson for reference)

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't disagree, but the question is currently deleted.  It seems like a waste of time to undelete it, reopen it, close it as a duplicate, and then delete it again.

Comment: @ryang I very much appreciate you mathsplaining to me what it is that I misunderstand.  However, I see *both* questions as fundamentally being about what quantifiers mean.  Neither is a very good question (in my opinion), but an answer to one could easily be an answer to the other with very little editing.  For example, you could make some very small edits to your answer and post it to the older question.  The goal of the site is to create a repository of question and answers---lumping together closely related questions improves the overall quality of that respository.

Comment: There are other related questions:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1593297/, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4207093/, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4308984/.  There are probably others.  This seems like a good candidate for a nicely written FAQ post.

Comment: Have looked through all 4 suggested links: the 5 posts collectively are at best cousins. Distilling such Questions into a bigass FAQ is as reasonable/realistic and fair as doing likewise for Questions related to parabolic curves.

Answer (score 3):

**Reopened.**

Please consider reopening [Planar Quartic Curve invariants for number of connex components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4565626/planar-quartic-curve-invariants-for-number-of-connex-components).  This question was originally unclear because it did not explain that it was working over $\mathbb{R}$, but now it has been edited to be clear.

Answer (score 3):

**Reopened**

Please consider reopening [Dodechadron, angle between edge and face.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605339/dodechadron-angle-between-edge-and-face).  This is a natural question of broad interest presented with clear motivation.  It seems to me that questions like these are one of the ideal purposes of this site: someone has a math question that they need an answer to for some application (not just some homework exercise they want someone to answer for them) but which is beyond their knowledge, and they are unable to find an answer elsewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

**Reopened**

I would like to request reopening for: [Find the minimum of $\sqrt{\cos x+3}+\sqrt{2\sin x+7}$ without derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612214/find-the-minimum-of-sqrt-cos-x3-sqrt2-sin-x7-without-derivative)

This is a very clearly posed question which the OP has made considerable and clear effort into and has attracted a high quality answer. The close reason seems unusual to me as knowing the source of the question does not change the quality of the post.

Answer (score 3):

The following two questions were deleted by the Community bot, though neither seems to fit the automatic deletion criteria.

[How do you factorise $x^2+7xy+my^2-5x+43y-24$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712437/how-do-you-factorise-x27xymy2-5x43y-24)

    [Factorize $-16x^3+36x^2-24x+5$ without using calculator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4692956/factorize-16x336x2-24x5-without-using-calculator)

On a closer look, they were both posted by an (ex-)user, "*destroyed*" by the same Community bot.

Don't know whether it is appropriate to list such questions here, and could not find any guidance about that on a quick search. Assuming it *is*, IMHO the questions did not deserve deletion on their own merits.

---

[ *EDIT* ] More upvoted questions with upvoted answers that got "destroyed" alongside the user are listed in google's cache of the profile (while it lasts). I am not saying that any of those is irreplaceably valuable, just that it looks odd to 10k+ users who happen upon them to see an otherwise OK question deleted by the Community bot without an apparent reason. Those who dig into the timeline will be twice confused to see it was done because of "user destroyed", typically reserved for spam or rude/abusive behavior, neither of which applies to those questions.

Comment: Some context on "destroyed" is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user).

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the link. Some more on the same topic [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338527/) on a different SE site, which appears to confirm that "destroyed" users get listed as "by Community bot" in the timeline. However, neither of these provides any advice or direction about undeleting "destroyed" questions.

Comment: @dxiv Undeleting such a question is the same as undeleting any other question.  That being said, is there any great value in keeping either of these around?  Don't we have enough questions asking about factoring polynomials already?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I believe what I wrote answers that part ("*not saying that any of those is irreplaceably valuable*"). But that was not the point. What looks somewhat arbitrary here is punishing an otherwise OK question (alongside with its answers) for unrelated/untold sins of the asker.

Comment: @dxiv No question is being "punished".  This is what happens when an account is destroyed.  Note that accounts are *rarely* destroyed, and that destruction of an account is typically related to a *lot* of disruptive behaviour.  I don't know what happened in this case, (as I am not currently moderating), but it is highly likely that the user earned the destruction of their account.  Do you really expect moderators to have to go through everything that a destroyed account has posted in order to find the appropriate material from the inappropriate?

Comment: "Do you really expect moderators to have to go through everything that a destroyed account has posted in order to find the appropriate material from the inappropriate?" @Xander, the moderators could delegate that task to trusted users.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The deletion of content is automatic, and happens when the user is destroyed.  What you are proposing would require some major *technical* changes to the way the site works.  There is nothing that can be done at a Math SE level to change this.  If you think that it is worth the effort, I would suggest that you bring this up on the main meta.

Comment: @Xander, "Undeleting such a question is the same as undeleting any other question." If I understand that correctly, all it would take is a message from a moderator to a trusted user saying "please have a look at the following list of deleted questions from a destroyed user and report back to me on which ones, if any, you think are appropriate for our website". No technical changes, and nothing that can't be done at the Math SE level.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If you say so.  Personally, I have no desire to increasing the complexity of a mostly automatic process in order to save the one-in-a-thousand question which *might* be of some value.  If you can convince another moderator to spend their time in this manner, be my guest.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What you propose would make sense, unfortunately I don't expect the idea to fly (as confirmed already). The blanket "destroy" rules in effect are probably justified in the majority of cases of blatant spam or abuse. No less importantly, they are safest and most convenient for the mods. I guess atypical cases like the one here are rare enough that they don't truly care about such collateral damage. FWIW the user in question had been around for several months, and was just under 500 rep, which is the threshold past which they would have been suspended/deleted rather than destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

**Reopened**

Request to reopen the following question [Proof of the Existence of All Phone Numbers in Pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495590/proof-of-the-existence-of-all-phone-numbers-in-pi).

Related meta dicussion: [Should this special case question (that has a proof) be marked as a duplicate of the general case question (that doesn't have a proof)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/should-this-special-case-question-that-has-a-proof-be-marked-as-a-duplicate-of?noredirect=1#comment169575_35940)

> I recently found this question: [Proof of the Existence of All Phone Numbers in Pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495590/proof-of-the-existence-of-all-phone-numbers-in-pi)
>
> I understand why it can be seen as a duplicate of [Does π contain all possible number combinations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations), but the question is much more specific and there is a proof that doesn't need π to be a normal number: a proof by exhaustion.
>
> As discussed in [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495590/proof-of-the-existence-of-all-phone-numbers-in-pi#comment10099465_3495590), since the early 2000s, we know enough digits of π to prove that it contains all 10-digit number sequences with an exhaustive search. However, this proof wouldn't make sense as an answer to the question on all possible number combinations.

Comment: We even know that all digit strings of length $11$ occur. But what is then the question ? It follows from the known digits of $\pi$. A proof is obsolete.

Comment: Noone knows how this result can be extended to , say , the digit-strings with length $30$. We only know the above result because the digits have been calculated. Noone is able to predict anything here. So no , there is no alternative proof that does not use the awfully many calculated digits.

Comment: But to know that "all digit strings of length 11 occur" we need a computer-assisted proof. It doesn't follow directly from looking at the digits of π with the human eye due to the length of the search.

Comment: Anyway , we cannot prove the occurence of a given digit string in $\pi$ , unless we do not already know that it is there ans where. So, the only possibility we have with our current knowledge is to look at the digits , we have nothing better. And of course , we must trust the computer that the digits are correct. So I do not understand the point.

Comment: @Peter I think there are still interesting discussions to have regarding this exhaustive search. For instance, assuming the digits of π are distributed randomly, how many digits are expected to be required to have all the n-digit strings appear at least once? Also, there are interesting methods to verify that the digits are correct such as the BBP algorithm. I would gladly post an answer to the question to expand further on these discussions, but as long as the question is closed, I can't.

Comment: If you mean the shortcut to determine the digits without having to calculate all previous digits : For $\pi$ (and only for $\pi$) such a shortcut is actually known , but sadly only in base $2$. And although we do not need the complete binary expansion , we still cannot determine some binary digit immediately , it still takes a lot of time , if it comes "late" in $\pi$.

Comment: @Peter I mentioned the BBP algorithm because your said "And of course , we must trust the computer that the digits are correct". What I meant is that we can use BBP to check that the digits we are using are correct (to almost 100%), we don't have to trust them blindlly. See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMqdRu9gGGs&t=167s

Comment: As said, this algorithm only works in base 2  , so I see no possibility to check digits without computer help. We also cannot "prove" that the largest known prime is prime. We must trust the computer calculations. The situation is the same.

Comment: @Peter 1) The BBP algorithm is used to calculate digits in base 16 (hexadecimal). 2) There are ways to convert a base 16 number to base 10 (and vice versa), so this just adds an additional step to the checking process.

Comment: @Peter What do you mean by saying "a proof is obsolete"? Checking the known digits for all 10-digit strings is a proof. And considering that this question was closed as a duplicate of a question regarding the normality of $\pi$, which is unknown, it seems not to be too widely known that enough digits of $\pi$ are known to answer the question for 10-digit strings (at least among the close voters).

Comment: In any case, it seems clear to me that a question whose answer is known cannot be a duplicate to a question whose answer is unknown. We also do not close a question asking if there are infinitely many primes as a duplicate of a question asking if there are infinitely many prime twins just because a positive answer to the second question would imply a positive answer to the first.

Answer (score 3):

**Undeleted**

I am requesting to reopen ["Bounding with exponential Markov inequality"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4766456/bounding-with-exponential-markov-inequality).

The asker posted a question and showed the work that they had done so far. They explained where they got stuck (can't show $at-\phi(t)$ is positive), and their unsuccessful attempts (Taylor expansion). I explained why they were attempting to prove the wrong thing ($at-\phi(t)$ need not be positive, but rather they should show that $\sup_t (at - \phi(t))$ is positive) and provided a path to show this, along with some context.

The asker deleted their question after I posted my answer. Could the question be reopened? I think my answer could be useful to others.

Comment: By the way, deletion of a question after answers is cause for moderator intervention as well - flagging can help with this sort of thing too.

Answer (score 3):

**Reopened**

Please consider voting to reopen the following question: [Does $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828778/does-mathbbr-mathbbq-contain-a-subgroup-isomorphic-to-mathbbq)

It was closed by a moderator, but I consider it to have met the context standards on this site. The question is completely clear, it doesn't appear to be a routine homework exercise, and the asker has suggested possible strategies for solving the problem. I have also searched for possible duplicates, and I can't find any. I can't see what additional context would improve the question.

[Disclosure: I have answered the question.]

Answer (score 2):

[**Closed as duplicate**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3748257/revisions)

I don't know if I can use this thread for closing a question as a duplicate, but let me try.

Please vote for closing this question [Intersection of Cyclotomic Extensions - gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748257) as a duplicate. Link for the dupe can be found under the question.

Comment: Why the need to post here, will it not be closed via the normal pathway of reviews?

Comment: I guess not....

Comment: I know, else you wouldn't have posted here, but "why" still remains? I filtered the close queue by dupes and yours was the third post to be reviewed for me. (I would rather not vote because I have no idea what the topic is)

Comment: I had other experiences with similar dupes that never closed as such.

Comment: Well this arguably doesn't belong here, but I think you might find support in the CURED room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured

Comment: @CalvinKhor fyi: As I stated when I created the [original thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6424) 10 years ago: "The purpose of this thread is to help focus the attention of the community on posts that may require exceptional handling".  Some dupe closures may indeed require exceptional handling, since many (queue) reviewers have neither the time nor expertise to properly  judge them.

Comment: I have voted to close as duplicate, and I agree with the direction of closing. However I think it would be good to disclose in such cases that you bring to the attention of Meta Math.SE that you have edited the Q being closed to more closely resemble the older Q.  I agree with your edit (some domain knowledge is useful to appreciate the issues).

Comment: There's a [duplicate thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24972/the-duplicate-thread) that you might use

Comment: @Bill I did think of you as I recall you pointing that out in last year’s thread. But I don’t think user26857 has made a case for why it requires such handling. Perhaps this is instead obvious to you from the content. In addition, just as we ask for posts to make it through the reopen queue before posting here, I think it would have been better if user was more patient. All this to say well. I don’t really have any horse in the race and I didn’t vote on this answer.

Comment: @ArcticChar There shouldn't be a separate dupe thread. Those requests belong here, cf. my prior comment. The (original) purpose of the thread is to handle all such exceptional requests - which localizes front page resources to one slot, minimizes bumping, etc, cf, my prior comment.

Comment: @Calvin  One can argue, why post a reopen request: "will it not be [reopened] via the normal pathway of reviews?"  There are avenues for reopening via queues.  Just like there are for closure.  If you think a separate thread is needed for reopening, for which there is a devoted queue, then it only makes sense that this thread should allow for close votes.   Undeletion requestions are a separate issue, and belong here.  What's good for the gander is good for the goose, wrt Reopen/close votes.

Comment: @amWhy my point is not that the answer should never have been posted. But the answer was posted  at soon after their first close vote (I forget the timing now, this was last week.) certainly we do not want every reopen vote to be posted here. So if it requires ‘exceptional handling’ perhaps a brief explanation why would be good? In addition I’d like to ask, do you agree that the post  could have also been closed via CURED?

Comment: Calvin One could respond to your first post "Why the need to post here, in this thread, when the moderator tools can accomplish the same?"

Answer (score 2):

[**Undeleted** (but still closed)](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4202743/revisions), Deleted, Undeleted (after 3 months!), [**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4202743/timeline)

[“Does it make sense to try to extend the concept of a raised set to a real number?”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202743/does-it-make-sense-to-try-to-extend-the-concept-of-a-raised-set-to-a-real-number) asks an easily intelligible question: can one can make sense of the notation $\Bbb R^x$ even when $x$ is a non-integer.  It was closed, without comment, as “off-topic”, and then deleted.

I considered the question on-topic and contributed an answer. My answer included some elementary remarks and then citations to pertinent mathematical research, published in the *American Mathematical Monthly*.  In my mind, this should be sufficient to show that the issue is neither “off-topic” or “not about mathematics”.

Comment: FYI:  two of the five close votes were for "lacking context".  For what it is worth, I agree with those voters.  As I read the question it is "Does $\mathbb{R}^t$ make sense for arbitrary $t$ and can I publish it?"  (I am guessing that the second part of that question is the bit that the remaining three voters felt was off-topic).  That being said, your *answer* is nice---you might consider [rewriting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32402/) the question.

Comment: Why did you answer a question lacking any and all context, @MJD, and why now, five months after the post's appropriate deletion, does this concern you?

Comment: @Delete-voters. Requests ("answers") in this thread should not be deleted, e.g. see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today#comment159858_34421) moderator comment. This is a longstanding policy.

Comment: @XanderHenderson The question doesn't say anything about publishing the result. It says “is it possible to make a paper out of it?”  I took this to mean something like a high school term paper. We don't know what the questioner did mean. I wish people here would be a little more charitable and a little less hasty when judging the intentions of strangers who might be children, might not be writing in their first language, and might be from places where the exact nuances of English are different from those of their own dialect.

Comment: @MJD I did not interpret the sentence in the same way you did, which I think lends credence to the argument that the question is unclear.  And *if* your interpretation is correct, the question is still off-topic, as that particular question is a matter of opinion, and is best posed to an advisor or instructor who might ultimately have to *grade* that paper.

Answer (score 2):

**[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4444518/timeline)**

The question [Are there any usages for growth rate that are relatively easy to show?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444518/are-there-any-usages-for-growth-rate-that-are-relatively-easy-to-show) was closed for not providing context. The context is brief but clear, including mention of growth rates and Gromov's polynomial growth theorem, and a request for some simple implications of growth rates. It's a unique question for this site and there could be some valuable answers (I made such a comment already, in lieu of being able to make an answer).

Comment: As noted in the comments below that question, the text being used is not mentioned, nor are their links to the mentioned Wikipedia pages.  Moreover, one of the comments seems make it clear that the question itself is not as clear as you suggest:  "Well, Gromov's result is rather concrete - see wikipedia. You can talk about it without giving a proof. Certainly you should ask your adviser for the seminar for more details on your topic. It seems that you need to present some of the basics on geometric group theory, too"

Comment: I am also concerned that the question is looking for "trivial" and "intuitive" examples, which is rather a matter of opinion (again, see the comment I quoted above).  Personally, I do not believe that this question is a very strong candidate for reopening in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

**Undeleted and reopened.**

Please consider reopening the following question:

[In what sense is $\Bbb R(x)$ an "instantiation" of the hyperreals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4454100/104041)

It seems to have been closed simply because $\Bbb R(x)$ is *not* an "instantiation" of hyperreal numbers in the strict sense of the word, rather than there being an issue with the question *itself*.

It was deleted by a bot.

It has, in the past, been undeleted and reopened; I made a case for it that goes something like this:

- The question has been answered in error by a well-established & respected user, only to have that answer deleted as incorrect. Surely, then, there is enough of a misunderstanding about hyperreal numbers for there to be a need for the question.
- The proposed duplicate doesn't mention $\Bbb R(x)$. Since the video in question makes the analogy between $\Bbb R(x)$ and hyperreal numbers, there must be *some sense* in the analogy, right? This needs addressing and the duplicate does not do so.
- It has context. I put a lot of effort into the question and I believe it shows.

In the comments on the question, there is a link to a valuable chat discussion on hyperreals.

A particular user has agreed to answer the question if it is reopened again.

Comment: Posts containing advertising for bad made up videos do not belong on this site. Instead of complaining why do you not just improve the question so that it deserves an undeletion ?

Comment: Yes the given dupe  is a very poor choice.  You may find helpful the links I give [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63996/242).

Comment: As I said [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61445462#61445462), @Peter, it is not an advertisement; I don't see how you can make that claim. How am I to ask what is meant by the terminology *without referencing where I encountered it?*

Answer (score 2):

**[Undeleted and Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4478677/timeline)**

Please vote for undeleting [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478677/determinining-uniform-convergence-for-f-nx-sum-k-1n-frackk2x22n).

This question was closed 11 days ago and deleted 8 days ago. I'm still confused by the deletion. In my opinion, this question didn't miss any contexts. He knows the limit of $f_n$, but he just didn’t know how to prove the uniform convergence, so he asked in MSE. It is a very good question, in my opinion, so I would like to take some time writting an answer for it.

What's more, the question owns 3 upvotes and 1 bookmark; my answer was accepted by OP and owns 4 upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

[Reopened.](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4519269/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries)

Please consider reopening [$p$-cycle in $S_p$ lies in certain subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519269/p-cycle-in-s-p-lies-in-certain-subgroup), a question about how to prove a nontrivial result mentioned without proof in a paper.  It is not clear to me what additional context anyone would want for this question beyond the linked paper, or how the site would be better off without this question and others like it.

Comment: This has been re-closed.

Answer (score 2):

**[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4572181/timeline#history_844edd39-ad57-40af-8d10-aa76d1f7f9e3)**

Please consider reopening [inner products on polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572181/inner-products-on-polynomials), a natural question presented with plenty of context.  It is entirely mysterious to me why it was closed or what additional context anyone wants from it.

Comment: Preceding the question , there is a note on a basic case, and that's enough motivation/context for this question.

Answer (score 2):

**[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4570652/timeline#history_9dc3beed-cf1d-4f46-ac62-38c9c4138c62)**

I want to request to reopen [Polynomial Approximation of Multiplicative Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4570652/polynomial-approximation-of-multiplicative-function), or receiving advice on how I can further improve the problem such that it meets the standard of Math Stack Exchange.

The feedback I received is

> Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

However, I did go though forms of context one by one, and I am uncertain about what type of context is missing.

- Motivation

  - My recent edit added a brief summary to the motivation of the question
- Personal Background

  - My recent edit added my personal background (an undergraduate studying first number theory class)
- Definitions

  - The question includes a hyperlink to Wikipedia page of multiplicative function, to clarify that the "multiplicative function" is referring to multiplicative function in number theory.
- Possible strategies & Include your work

  - The question includes my own attempt at answering the question (the statement is false), and a possible route to the answer (estimating the growth of $f(p^a) = p^{p^a}$).

Answer (score 2):

**Undeleted**, as requested. (Thanks.)

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908766/using-a-change-of-variable-to-reduce-a-linear-2nd-order-pde-to-a-1st-order-pde) old Question, currently at a +1 score, was considered abandoned, then autodeleted, by the roomba 2 yrs ago.

For completeness, I've just edited it to add a self-Answer. If you feel that this page is worth restoring, just vote to Undelete it, after which I shall convert the addendum into an actual self-Answer for self-acceptance (the green tick).

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

**Reopened**

[Are my odds higher predicting a $50/50$ bet with a constant or picking a random number each time?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699908/are-my-odds-higher-predicting-a-50-50-bet-with-a-constant-or-picking-a-random)

I added the last part:

> The context is this - casino games - more specifically dice ones.

After asked for context 2 times - while I think that was not necessary. (for the curios It's a game on the online casino where you predict if a number is above or below another number (which can be chosen to be 50 (where the range is [0, 100])).

I honestly think this question is clear as it stands and should not be closed.

Anyway as per observation I replaced the above with the following (as of now):

> I initially had this theory in my head that placing random bets each
> time, rather than having a constant to compare with all the time - has
> sorta the properties of having a higher chance to match because of the
> possible cases where the random numbers I'm predicting stray from the
> constant.
>
> Also I had concerns on the other hand that if Each time I predict
> random - since it's random on the both ends - it may have less chance
> to match as well.
>
> My question is simple if any of those above concerns hold any merit.

There were also concerns about the rules of modifying the balance which I cleared up as well - in my recent edit.

Comment: You may add the background about your knowledge in probability, also, why you think  that placing random bets each time, rather than having a constant to compare with all the time is better using the probability knowledge you know.

Comment: @ArcticChar I just added that?

Comment: So what is your background in probability? I can't find that in the post.

Comment: @ArcticChar None - added that too.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider reopening [In what sense is the sphere the limit of convex polyhedra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4644501/in-what-sense-is-the-sphere-the-limit-of-convex-polyhedra), a very natural question motivated by an obvious curiosity about how to formalize a well-known intuitive idea.  It is unclear to me why it was closed or what additional context anyone would want from such a question.

Comment: The post has now been reopened.

Answer (score 2):

**Re-opened.**

Please consider reopening [Real-valued dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880719/real-valued-dimension), a natural and nontrivial question motivated by an obvious natural curiosity.  It's unclear to me what additional context anyone thinks it needs.  It seems to me that this is exactly the sort of question that this site was built for: questions that may naturally occur to many people (not just some exercise that is of no particular interest), do not have obvious or "standard" answers that can be found in every textbook on the subject, and by having an answer here the answer will be easily findable with a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

[**Reopened**](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4484246/timeline)

I think that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484246/every-real-solution-of-x3x3-0-is-irrational) should not have been closed as a duplicate. It is tagged [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification) - the asker does not want to know how the proposition is proved, but to know if their own proof is valid.

Comment: From the main thread, "Further, leaving it open almost always results in users posting many duplicate answers, which leads to rampant duplication - making it difficult if not impossible to locate "best" answers." strikes at the heart of the debate. This question is tagged solution-verification, yet there is very little confidence that the next answerer will respect this.

Answer (score 1):

**Reopened** (yay)

[My Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/226679/21813) is ostensibly similar to [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/223521/21813) as they refer to and are illustrated by the same mathematical exercise.

However, they do not duplicate each other, because

- my Question queries about **the derivation of the upper bound of a particular detail used to algorithmically obtain the solutions**, while the other Question queries about **the number of solutions**.
- none of my Question's Answers address the latter Question, and none of the other Question's Answers *even indirectly* address my Question.

To better focus my Question (and to clarify the misunderstanding), I've boldfaced its thesis “**But why the upper bound $\frac r2$ for $n\,?$**” Again: this issue is neither raised nor directly nor indirectly addressed in the other Question.

Hopefully, this explanation is sufficiently persuasive.

Answer (score 1):

**UNDELETED**

The following was closed and deleted, presumably because it contains two exercises, and a cursory reading might place it, therefore, as needing focus; it does not: it's about an apparent contradiction in Robinson's book on group theory between the two exercises.

[Two exercises by Robinson on supersolvable groups seem to contradict.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4361739/104041)

Answer (score 1):

**Deleted, Undeleted, auto-deleted**

Request to reopen my question "[What is the use of the $\ell^2$ spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4748937/1204653)". It was once closed as lacking context, but was reopened after the context was added. Then it was closed for "This question needs to be more focused". It is more narrowly focused than the other questions which is not closed ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556307/what-are-the-applications-of-functional-analysis)). I further narrowed the focus to $p=2$, but it was left closed in review. I focused even more narrowly to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$. There is no close-voter explaining how narrow is enough.

It is almost José Carlos Santos and Another User who are trying to close this question and they leave no comments.

Comment: The most recent closure had nothing to do with the two users you name. It was a unilateral action by a moderator, who has left several comments.

Comment: The non-closed questions you cite are all old, with the one you give here being from 2015. Site norms and conventions change over time, and generally these kinds of questions are closed now. To make a case for your one to be reopened, you'd need to convince the readers/voters/moderator that the information is truly not readily available - for example, search in a couple of standard books in the area, or act on Xander's first comment and look on the site. If these actions answer your question then great! If they don't, then it makes a better case to reopen the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson See the History.  left closed in review by José Carlos Santos, Another User and Arctic Char.

Comment: I did see the history, Htmm, and it confirms my comment in all its particulars.

Comment: As one of the user who voted to "leave closed" your post: I agree with everything Severin Schraven said there.

Answer (score 1):

I request to please review The question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207341/if-all-the-sides-of-an-n-sided-polygon-are-equal-is-it-always-a-regular-polygon

I have provided My own attempts to understand the concept, and asked a genuine question that bothered me, Recently I was Banned from Asking questions On MSE, since then I have been trying to review posts that were deleted or closed or received negative votes, Also I have been contributing to MSE by providing answers to questions that I know the solution of..

Answer (score 0):

**[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4351990/revisions).**

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351990/what-are-the-connections-between-representation-theory-and-differential-equation) was just closed as opinion based. It is not opinion based (what are the opinions on which it is based?) and should be reopened. The question asks about connections between PDE and representation theory. A similar, if not the same, question exists on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335116/is-there-a-connection-between-representation-theory-and-pdes) since 2019. It is upvoted many times and has several answers.

Comment: I made some comments regarding this in the main thread itself. The "opinion" on which it is based seems to be whether the theory of automorphic forms falls under DE or not. Nevertheless, the MO thread seems to be a fairly objective/fact-based answer to the question. While the author revealed themselves to be beginning their Masters, a few close and down votes have come before this comment : that information is essential for deciphering the level of the student, and without it someone would have had to opine about the author's preference/aptitude for a certain subject.

Comment: That this is not opinion-based is not a fact but again an opinion-based statement. To me , it is definitely opinion-based. Therefore I cannot understand why it was reopened.

Answer (score 0):

**[Reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4362596/revisions), reclosed, deleted**

I edited [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4362596/is-sqrt317-0-12345-algebraic). Can you reopen it? I accept the answer.

@banana told me to do it

Sorry why my answer gets into comments? < 50 reputation?

Comment: The system automatically converts very short answers into comments under certain conditions, but this is not reputation-based: you can take a look at “[Answer appears automatically converted as a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950)” on [metase] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

##### [Reopened after moderator intervention](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2706956/timeline#history_0398dacd-928e-4664-bdf6-dbb1fb20cf3b)

While reading an [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309533) to *[What should I do if I find the answer to an old question of mine that was automatically deleted as abandoned?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309526/what-should-i-do-if-i-find-the-answer-to-an-old-question-of-mine-that-was-automa)* over at the *main StackExchange Meta site*, I came across the following comments:

---

> **This topic [math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706956](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706956/triangle-inequality-fracaba2-b2-fracbcb2-c2-fracca) with beautiful
> problem and my nice answer was deleted. How can we undelete this
> topic?** Thank you! –  Michael Rozenberg  Aug 16, 2018

> @MichaelRozenberg I'm afraid I probably wouldn't know enough to be
> able to comment on that Q&A even if I could see it. If you can tell
> what the problem with the question is and can fix it, edit and ask the
> community to undelete. Or raise the question on your site's meta. I
> don't know how things work on Math, but I've seen the community fix
> and undelete questions on other sites, if the problem is fixable. –
> Monica Cellio  Aug 16, 2018 at 17:08

---

*To justify a variance from the fourth guideline above...*

While [Michael Rozenberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/190319/michael-rozenberg) appears to still be active on [Mathematics 'proper'](https://math.stackexchange.com/), he does not seem to have an account at all here on *Maths Meta*.

As I don't know if anyone *(e.g. the original question author)* has followed up on why that answered question about triangle inequalities was deleted *(and I can't view the deleted question to evaluate it myself, of course)*, I am posting it here in case there is anything promising within the referenced question and/or answer!

- Jim

Comment: Hi Jim, I give credit to MR for the answer (and his many answers over the years) , and this question looks rescuable, because it isn't a duplicate, and apart from lacking context has no other problem. For example, I believe that if we can edit the Euler and Gerritsen inequalities into the post, we can call for undeletion.  Guidelines for context edits and rewrites will ensure that I can insert the required definitions, so I will do it myself. In hindsight, there *is* an answer that uses Gerritsen's inequality, so it is useful eventually. Therefore, I will edit the post shortly.

Comment: The post has been deleted by a moderator, so cannot be undeleted by users. I have still edited the post, and will probably flag for undeletion.

Comment: *Reopened now, enjoy*

Comment: Thank you for improving the question.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @Sarvesh  In truth, it was not reopened here. It lives where it belongs.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer: You rewarded a chronic PSQ poster, and a chronic PSQ answerer. Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

[Reopened, Re-closed, reopened](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4511317/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries)

Please consider reopening [Show that the $\ell_p$ norm of $x$ as $p \to 0$ is the support of $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4511317)

The post is edited and the context is quite clear as OP mentioned in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511317/show-that-the-l-p-norm-of-x-as-p-to-0-is-the-support-of-x#comment9472264_4511317).

Comment: I actually don't agree that the OP's mention of a page in a linked preview (of a $$60+ book) is proper or clear context.  The proposition itself seems relatively easy to demonstrate (as it follows from solving the case $n=1$).  Before banging our heads over trying to get the OP to provide context, perhaps we should check for potential duplicates?

Comment: See my comments under that post, and also : this book is open-source, see [here](https://personal.utdallas.edu/~m.vidyasagar/Fall-2015/6v80/CS-Notes.pdf). It is not the demonstration that one must focus on here : given that the author is coming from the point of view of *compressed sensing*, answering this question requires one to also understand how and why this question relates to CS : the answer being that as an identity, it is used for $l_0$ norm minimization problems, which form a large part of sparse matrix linear algebra. This question is relevant beyond the mere identity via context

Comment: @hardmath: I do not think that "the OP's mention of a page" alone is context. "**Context**" means a lot of things. To me, the very definition of the $l_p$ norm and the $\textrm{supp}$ are all context. //   If it were to be closed as a duplicate, it should be reopened first I suppose. What is a "$$60+ book"?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reopening [Are there any other fraction-to-decimal conversions like $\frac{5}{2} = 2.5$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4596205/are-there-any-other-fraction-to-decimal-conversions-like-frac52-2-5).  This is a nontrivial question motivated by an obvious natural curiousity.  It is not clear to me what additional context anyone would expect or want a question like this to have, or how the site would be better off without this question and others like it.

Comment: It needs a computer program to test for these numbers, and/or a few more observations on $a,b$ (elimination of a few cases, necessary/sufficient conditions) right now.

Comment: The post is now repoened.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened; reclosed as not suitable; deleted by Community Bot**

Please consider reopening https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666575/g-is-a-p-group-implies-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-p-is-central/4666624#4666624

It has been closed as a duplicate but the prior problem was asking for finite groups only, while the text of the new question explicitly asked for infinite groups to be covered.

Thanks for your time

Comment: As it stands the question is a problem-statement question: it provides no context, no effort and doesn't meet the site standards (which I note was mentioned to you as a comment to the answer you've provided).  The question needs to be improved before reopening.

Comment: As @postmortes states, the question does not meet the quality guidelines for the site.  I have closed the question for that reason.  The banner at the top of the question should now point you in the direction of advice on asking questions.

Comment: Let's be clear. I requested that this not be closed as a duplicate. You have fixed that - thank you. On site standards, you guys are the experts and I am not requesting that you open it now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

**Undeleted, and then deleted again**

Please consider undeleting the following question about limits to infinity: [What makes a number big?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342155/what-makes-a-number-big)

I think this question meets the context standards set out on this site, since it identifies a hand-wavey explanation that I suspect many people  received when they are first introduced to limits, namely that a limit to infinity is "the value of the function as $x$ gets really big". I certainly remember hearing variants of this "explanation" when I was at school, e.g. that the limit to infinity tells you "what happens when $x$ blows up".

Of course, that "explanation" falls far short of the standards of rigorous mathematics, but that is precisely the reason the question was asked in the first place.

Comment: Okay, folks, deleting answers in this thread is generally not okay.  Downvote if you disagree, but please do not delete.  If nothing else, it is best that the record remain public.

Comment: The question on main has a very colorful history. Posted 26 Dec 21 4:12; closed 9:16; opened 27 Dec 21 2:09; closed 13:34; deleted 15:08; undeleted 14 Feb 22 12:52; deleted 28 Feb 22 10:10; undeleted 9 Mar 22 7:21; deleted 6 June 22 5:06; undeleted 7 Aug 23 18:33. And I've left out several instances of "left closed in review".

Comment: @Gerry What makes a history colorful? Big numbers?

Comment: @Bill, would you prefer "eventful"?

Comment: @Gerry It was wordplay on the question title ("what makes a number big?").

Comment: @Bill, what makes a comment subtle?

Comment: The question has been deleted again. I would appreciate if any of the delete voters could explain their reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened**

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686704/triviality-of-line-bundles/4686767#4686767) question was closed for lack of context, though the question is simple enough to stand on its own. I spent quite some time coming up with an answer only to have the question closed shortly before my answer was posted and think that the methods used in the answer provide sufficient motivation.

Comment: Given that the question is *unarguably* a PSQ, likely many users will disagree with reopening unless the question is improved, cf. [EOQS site policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242)

Comment: It's a question about line bundles on a manifold, it has a long & detailed answer. The question currently has two votes to delete, and I think it would be sad if the content of that answer were to be removed from this site.

Comment: @Gerry Then why not improve the question to prevent that?

Comment: @Bill, there is a general reason, and a specific reason. The general reason is that many of our fellow users believe that only the person posting a poor question is allowed to improve it. No one else is allowed to put words into that poster's mouth, as it were. The specific reason is that I wouldn't know a line bundle on a manifold from a homotopy type-theory, so I am singularly unsuited to improving that particular question.

Comment: In general, I don't think a question can/should be saved by it's answer. Any answerer has a responsibility to ensure that they answer good question, and "good" isn't just about mathematical quality (as this is not MathOverflow).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I used to believe that as well. The reason behind that thinking was that we shouldn't be guessing any posters' intentions from their poor question at all lest we get it wrong, and that if we were to do that, then many posters would just dump their question knowing that someone would improve it, so they're not putting as much effort into their argument. Over time, I think I've come to realize that the second argument is a slippery slope and the first can be countered by placing some trust on editors to get things right.

Answer (score 0):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733432/applications-of-functions

I wrote an answer to this five years ago. Apparently the OP vandalized their question, so it eventually got deleted. But now I can't even see what the original question was; I can only see the most recent version. I think it should be undeleted and rolled back.

It was about determining the five parameters in $f(x)=a+b\exp(cx)\cos(dx+e)$, given only the graph $y=f(x)$.

Comment: The edit history can be viewed by clicking on the [date shown to the left of where of post authorship is shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2733432/revisions).  Even without the assumed vandalism, the Question strikes me as as bare problem statement, i.e. lacking context.  Although I'm a curve-fitting fanboy, I don't think it is suitable as a Question for the site (but I can see you put much effort into your Answer).  The OP has not been seen for years now.

Comment: No, it cannot be viewed by low-rep users like me.

Comment: In particular, I can't see whether it was or wasn't a good question at any time.

Comment: The original version (current one is edit 2) shows [this image of a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVP2C.png) and asks how to fit a function (omitting the constant offset $a$ as you relate it above).  The OP never supplied the missing parameter nor responded to Comments by you and JJacquelin.  If it's important to get your Answer back, I'd email it to you (reach me at username at gmail).

Comment: I have access to the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: It looks like the question has been rolled back. (I didn't notice until now.) A little thank to @user1729. [[sic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240010/why-cant-thanks-ever-be-singular-as-a-noun)]

Answer (score 0):

Request to undelete my post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4698344/861687. This question was deleted by community bot. The only reason I see for deletion is downvote. Perhaps some user find it multiple questions in one post but I asked only one question. Since comments are “temporary”, I edited my post to include main idea of answer. I don’t know what algorithm is being used for community bot, but certainly they want to suppress net downvote posts.

Comment: This was auto-deleted by the community user [because it had a score of -1 or lower and no answers, no active bounty, and no lock](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions). How do you plan to improve the question, and why didn't you make any improvements in the last month?

Comment: @KReiser that post is a simple question not a thesis, how can I improve it (genuinely)? I can’t improve all my $280$ questions post to keep them “active”. It seems like nowadays posts are temporary too.

Comment: For one, you're asking three separate questions in one post, which was noted in the comments on the day you made your post. You don't have to edit all of your posts all of the time (over-editing can be a problem too) but when you get immediate feedback like the comment to ask one question at a time plus two downvotes on the same day you make your post, I don't understand why you wouldn't try addressing that until a month passes and your post is automatically deleted. (The comment about posts being temporary is a red herring - do you really want every post at -2 and no answers hanging around?)

Comment: @KReiser I already mentioned in above answer and comment of that post that I asked **one** question only. I just wrote entire theorem as it is written in book. I don’t know why you think I asked three separate questions. That post got downvoted because I was experiencing targeted downvoting during that time. Anyway I don’t care about downvotes. With multiple questions and downvotes (way to justify deletion of post) out of the way. Not all user prefer to write short answer in answer section, so they instead comment on post. That’s why I’m not surprised with no answer, I got answer in comment.

Comment: Your question can be interpreted in 2 separate ways, which makes it a bad question. Firstly, it could be a "check my proof" question of a 4 part question. Secondly, it could be asking to formalise your solution to part (iv). I'm guessing you wanted the second "formalise" one, but then why give both your solution and the solution in the book to the other 3 parts? What does it add? It is confusing. (If it does add something, then don't make the reader join the dots for themself, because everyone will join them differently.)

Comment: @user1729 I have edited my post.

Comment: Thanks, it looks better. However, you still have too much extra information. Why include Hungerford's proofs of the other parts? Also, if your "edit" at the end answers the question, then you should have added this as an answer rather than as an edit to the question.

Comment: @user1729 I will edit my post to exclude extra stuff. Since answer is not mine, I don't think it is appropriate to make other people comment into an answer, that is just my opinion.

Comment: In this situation, it would be appropriate to write an answer giving appropriate accreditation (e.g. link to the comments), and check the "community wiki" box. Community wiki's mean that the answer isn't due to a single person, and so noone gets reputation points. The system does not like questions which have no "answer", and so for example will delete them like what happened here.

Comment: @user1729 now unfortunately can't write answer. I don't know the exact statistic of unanswered question but significant number of post are unanswered and inactive then all post should be deleted not only few (randomly chosen). Posts are not lottery.

Comment: Deleted posts are not "randomly chosen". Your question satisfied specific conditions, so was automatically deleted. This was addressed in the first comment above, by KReiser.

Comment: @user1729 I don't need to emphasis how wide scope those conditions are. All most all (above 90%, just my guess) unanswered question falls into that category.

Comment: The issue is not with the conditions, but with your question(s). Your current draft is better, but could still be greatly improved. For example, it still contains too much extra content, and I also do not know why you are asking the question: (a) You have Hungerford's proof, why do you need another? (b) What do you not like about your existing proof? Why is it informal? Your reader is busy - guide them quickly to your issue rather than expecting them to spot why you think it is too informal on a first reading.

Comment: [This is my final comment though, as this is not the correct place for further suggestions for improvement.]

Answer (score 0):

**Undeleted**.

Consider undeleting [Taxi distance count to all lattice points at specified *distance* from the lattice origin and of a specified *dimensionality*?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4723745/21813) if you think that the Question-Answer pair is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

Please reopen this question , [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741751/calculate-the-angle-gamma)
I add clarification about the whole context , also I have added known and unknown variables

Comment: I think you meant to link to the closed question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741751/calculate-the-angle-gamma – the link you gave goes to a question you deleted.

Comment: yes, i have edited !!

Answer (score 0):

Please reopen

[Let $H,K \subseteq G$. Prove $H,K \lhd G$ and $|K| = [G:H]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4754366/104041)

It was closed as needing focus, but if you know the first homomorphism theorem of groups, it's one question (with a normality check that ensures you know which of $\ker\varphi$ and ${\rm im}\varphi$ is automatically normal).

I have answered the question.

Comment: Almost surely this is a dupe.

Comment: Find one and we'll know for sure, @BillDubuque.

Comment: Before posting your answer, your searched and failed to find a dupe?

Comment: Of course, @BillDubuque.

Comment: @Bill, it also copies an earlier answer that same day.

Comment: It wasn't copied, @amWhy; I explained it in more detail. That's allowed.

Comment: It don't think it should have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**Deleted**

I posted the question [Position of Mathematical Logic [closed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763846/position-of-mathematical-logic). It is closed as lacking context but it is unclear what context is missing.

I have added the following context.

- My work
- My bakground
- Definitions
- Motivation

However, reviewers, primarily José Carlos Santos, Another User, and Anne Bauval, leave questions closed **without a single comment each time**.

Since they won't write what context is missing (although I expect there is no missing context), the only thing I can do is keep adding context until they are satisfied.

However, I have now stopped adding context. This is because the moderators have threatened me by a private message. I will not copy and paste it here because it is private, but they told me to stop adding context or my account will be suspended.

Because of this I am currently unable to actively add context, so please reopen as is, or specify which context is lacking. I believe it is my legitimate right to respond to specific requests.

—

The question was deleted. I improved the question after that.

Xander Henderson says that the question has been edited 20+ times. That's because that the question was closed 19 times or left closed by the review, without commenting on which context is lacking. **If the lacking context was pointed out, all I needed was a single edit.** The only thing I can do is keep adding context until they are satisfied.I am just doing what I have to do.

Comment: (1) As a moderator, I cannot quote the message which was sent to you.  You, however, are free to share it with anyone.  The fact that you have chosen not to makes it difficult to point out how that is certainly not what the message said.

Comment: (2) The post in question has been edited 20+ times.  With most of those edits, you have elected to check the "This fixes the problems with this post" checkbox, which sent the question into the review queue 20ish times.  Most of those edits were very minor, and did not fix the underlying problems.  Either make substantive edits, or don't send the question for review.

Comment: (3) Adding more text is not necessarily adding more context.  A good question provide the necessary context, and don't waste the reader's time with extra information.  A good question lays out that information in an easy to read fashion (*not* here is my question, and here is a bullet-pointed list of "context", which I am adding to this question just because red tape says that I have to").  Attempt to write an exposition which *flows*, and is actually explanatory.

Comment: As an example, you use the abbreviations "ZFC" and "FOL" early in the text, and then define them much later.  If you believe that people require this definition, why not write something like "Mathematical logic uses set theory such as Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory (ZFC). ZFC is based on first order logic (FOL)."  This makes your question much easier to read.  I would suggest that you actually try to *read* your question, from start to finish.  Maybe even read it out loud.  See how it sounds.  If it doesn't sound good make fixes.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I appreciate the lengthy comment you wrote for me, but it is unfortunate that there is not a single mention of which context is missing.

Comment: They never say what context is missing because if they do, it will be fulfilled and the question will be reopened. What a nonconstructive behavior.

Comment: It is unfortunate that there are few helpful comments there, but Karl's comment is helpful and important - *why* are you asking this question? There are also other issues which are not about context, for example: questions with yes/no answers are not particularly suited to this site; questions should in general only be asking one question at a time; the hierarchy you state is unclear (e.g. *how* is it a hierarchy?). [There are no quick fixes here, and probably the best way to proceed is to find well-received questions of a similar type and try to emulate them.]

Comment: @user1729 I already read Karl’s comment and added context, but I added more in response to your comment. I will solve other issues but the first priority is the context issue, which is the current reason for the closure. I have already written a definition of hierarchy. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Power I do not think context is the only reason for the closure. People are unwilling to reopen a question with issues, regardless of the initial close reasons (again, it is unfortunate that there were few helpful comments). I really want to emphasise though that you need to rewrite this question to emulate good questions, rather than continual small edits.

Comment: @user1729 As I understand it, the context is the reason of the current closure. If there is another reason, it will first be reopened by resolving the context issue and then closed for another reason. If they keep requiring context when context is not real reason, without commenting on it, then that doesn’t make sense.

Comment: No, the question will nt be reopened and then immediately closed. That is both a waste of curator time and effort, and mechanically pointless, because the reopen reviews can be marked "leave closed" for "still has other issues".

Answer (score 0):

**Reopened 18 Nov 23; closed again 25 Nov 23, then deleted by Community Bot**

Please reopen

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4802630/104041

It has context.  The OP was overthinking the answer.

Note: I answered it.

Comment: I suspect that the problem statement has gotten a little garbled.  There would seem no point in requiring $G$ (a subgroup of an abelian, even cyclic, group) to have order $6$ unless one was also meant to have $a,b,c$ mutually distinct and different from $1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Re-opened**

[confused by nonconstructive equivalence relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4849335/25554) requests clarification of  a specific statement on a specific page of a specific textbook:

> I was reading "constructive analysis" by Bishop and right on page 15 he writes:…

And then the second paragraph describes the poster's confusion:

> What makes me confused is why …

There is no sense in which this could be considered “needing details or clarity”, and none of the people who voted to close left any comment explaining what details were missing or what they felt was unclear.

Comment: Reminder: "If you are involved in the thread which you post about (e.g., you asked the question or you answered it), please disclose this."

Comment: Thanks, I will remember to do that next time.

Comment: Actually, your last comment on the thread ("*I think I should probably not get farther into this without carefully looking at what Bishop actually says and how his book does things.*") actually proves that the question was needing details or clarity, so it wasn't wrong to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Please reopen this:

[An example of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that is used in number theory but cannot be written in terms of Peano arithmetic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886034/an-example-of-a-subset-of-mathbbn-that-is-used-in-number-theory-but-cannot)

The question is mine.

This is not duplicate.

Comment: To compensate for editing the Question to introduce a notion of "actually used in number theory", it would help Readers if you could make that notion more precise.  For example I'd be inclined to think that the construction of certain models within Peano arithmetic for fragments of elementary set theory would fall in a grey area, as regards the relative consistency of PA with such set theories is (for me) a kind of number theory.

Comment: *"Do not only post a request, like "request reopening of link". Instead, make a case for your concern."*

Comment: One of the original close-voters agrees that this is not a duplicate now.

Answer (score 0):

**[Undeleted.](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4889065/timeline#history_b0e6b3da-bff0-49f7-adf2-619b387dec3f)**

Would you please undelete this post? [Existence of an $L^2$ function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4889065)? I found it interesting, but the asker deleted it just after receiving an answer.

Comment: FYI, deletion after receiving an answer is worth flagging for moderator intervention.

Answer (score -1):

Please undelete and reopen

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4754844/104041

It was deleted, presumably, because some users do not like the fact that

$$x+1=x-2$$

has $x=\infty$ as a solution; a controversial opinion. The comments say the question is nonsense. It is not.

It is also claimed that it is a PSQ. How? The OP proposed that $\infty$ is a *root* (but not a *solution*); that's context. They wanted to understand it.

I have answered the question.

Comment: Reminder that per the guidelines above, if you are involved in the post you're requesting for (like having answered it, as you have done here) that you should note it in your request.

Comment: I see there's a vote to delete Shaun's question. I don't think we should delete good faith posts to this reopen-undeletion thread. It's enough to show disagreement via downvotes.

Comment: I think the linked question is low-quality, and even if it's fixed, it's answered [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/is-infinity-a-number) [on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260876/what-exactly-is-infinity) [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387286/is-infinity-larger-than-1).

Comment: Those aren't duplicates, @KReiser

Comment: I disagree - each of those questions has an answer that talks about why one cannot do standard arithmetic with infinity. Anyways, I'm not going to be using an undelete/reopen vote here, and I do not wish to continue the conversation further. Good day.

Answer (score -2):

Please consider reopening [Proving that $\langle x, y \rangle$ is a not principal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x, y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044158)

Although related, the current [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1872667), which is **closed** too, *asking for an example*, is not a duplicate. Moreover, the post is linked to a chain of questions that are **all closed**.

If this question is to be closed, there is supposed to be a better "duplicate" target: in the all *closed* chain of questions, **NONE** new answer is allowed to added.

Comment: [This proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1872824/242) in the linked dupe does exactly what the OP seeks (put $c = y\in\Bbb Q[y]$) so it is not clear what you mean by "better dupe target". There are many possible dupe targets (chase the links) for this common exercise, and nothing at all novel in the (duplicate) answers posted. [Your profile shows *zero* activity in abstract algebra. Experience in a field is usually necessary in order to properly assess duplicates].

Comment: It seems that you have a very different definition of "dupe" from mine, whatever it is. Experience in a field $\Large{\neq}$ activities in your mathSE profile. "better dupe" means one does not need to "chase the links", not to mention that it is linked to a closed question that may be voted to be deleted by users.

Comment: In my experience it is - esp. for most users whose tags don't go much beyond calculus. Please explain what you mean by a "better dupe target". We can easily add more dupe links.

Comment: Yes, usually, maybe.

Comment: Your recent comments (and votes) on main made it clear that you are strongly against abstract dupes. But this is only a *very slight* abstraction - viz. specializing the nonzero nonunit $c$ to $y\in \Bbb Q[y]\,$ in the Lemma in the dupe. It would be greatly obfuscatory to have separate questions for various choices of nonunits $c$ in motley domains. A primary goal of *abstract* algebra is to prove theorems at their natural level of abstraction - so they apply as widely as possible.

Comment: "Your recent comments (and votes) on main made it clear that you are strongly against abstract dupes." Please *don't* put labels on me Bill. I do not want to discuss anything in general under this thread.// Comments are not supposed to be answers in main; one should address [the issue Arturo mentioned in meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/coping-with-abstract-duplicate-questions#comment6091_1756) if one wants to handle abstract dupe: (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) *It would require the "survivor variant" to have answers that address both the general strategy (so as to be useful for future minor variants) and specific application to the question at hand (which shows how the general strategy applies to a specific problem). *

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981094/x-y-subset-mathbb-qx-y-is-not-a-principal-ideal) is probably a more exact dupe target (containing the "survivor variant").

Comment: @Sarves But that is already true for the existing linked dupe (case $K = \Bbb Q$; the simple proof works for coefficient field $K$ and no simplification arises when $K = \Bbb Q$)

Comment: @BillDubuque You're right, the same proof works with $K$ replaced by $\mathbb Q$, but I think you should leave a comment mentioning this , however obvious it might seem. Heck, I'll do it.

Comment: @Sarvesh Any student studying ideal theory in rings that doesn't see immediately how to specialize a theorem on fields to the field $\Bbb Q$ has seriously put the cart before the horse. This goes back to my original comment - it is crucial for those assessing dupes to have significant experience in the topic in order to understand which  inferences can be assumed trivial and left to the reader.

Comment: This post has been deleted.

Answer (score -2):

I answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3589372/) around 3 years ago.

7 months ago, it was commented, in bold no less, that there was an error. This brought my answer from a +4 score down to +2. I reviewed the comment and the supposed error did not feature in my answer. I explained as much in a comment back.
This morning I woke up and my answer score is -1 and my answer has been deleted. Another comment was left yesterday, this time decrying my comment as handwaving and claiming that I'm making the same error (to reiterate: I'm not) and showing it doesn't work with a counterexample against the wording of the question (which is specifically about a set of consecutive integers, like my answer).

I've since edited my answer to flesh out the details a bit more and really spell it out, but it feels very unfair to have someone declare and insist upon an error without really trying to understand my answer.

Comment: I'm just reading your answer, and the first issue I have is that there is no quantifier attached to the $a$ in the first bit of working. I presume it is an $\exists$, and comes after the initial $\forall$? I'm then unsure precisely what the $k$ is, but I don't think we can "match" $1\cdot2\cdots n$ with the sequence $(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)$, because we have no control over the $a$ - *unless* the $a$ is actually quantified by a $\forall$.

Comment: Another problem, which I think is the one BillDubuque is pointing out, is that your answer seems to only really rephrase the fact that "one in every $t$ consecutive integers is divisible by $t$." This is true, but more is needed here, as you will be double-counting these sequences. So you need to flesh out the claim "thus the same is true across the whole product".

Comment: (For example, for $4!$ we need sequences of $4$, $3$ and $2$ integers in our product, and **without further argument** these sequences need to be disjoint, i.e. we need to rewrite $4!$ as the product of $4+3+2=9$ consecutive integers, but this is impossible!)

Comment: I agree, $a$ ought to have it's own $\exists$. $a$ is decided by $k$ and $n$. If we are multiplying, as an example, $123\cdot \ldots \cdot 128$, then $n=6$ as there are six numbers, we pick $a=21$ as $21\cdot 6=126$ is in our set. Then our numbers go from $123\equiv 3 \pmod 6$ to $128\equiv 2 \pmod 6$.

Comment: Regarding the second problem, I can see the concern, however it works out with the same observation that we are cycling the residues $\mod n$. I fleshed out the details in what I added earlier, but in essence, if $n$ has a divisor $d$, there will be a number $x$ in our set with $x\equiv d\pmod n$. Take the same set I used earlier, we have $6=2\cdot 3$ and $123\equiv 3\pmod 6$ while $128=2\pmod 6$.

Comment: Instead of fleshing out the details below, you should edit your answer so that it is clearer in a first reading.

Comment: The argument is either incorrect or seriously incomplete. It is impossible to decide which since you have not supplied rigorous justification of the huge gap, i.e. *precisely* how the OP's claim is inferred from  "one in every $t$  consecutive integers is divisible by $t$".  I doubt that anyone has any idea how you propose to do so based on what you have written.

Answer (score -2):

**Undeleted by users then deleted by bot, then undeleted again by users, then deleted by post author on Jan. 30, 2024**

Please undelete and reopen this:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618260/104041

The question is mine.

---

I put an awful lot of effort into it.  The downvotes confuse me and I have no clue why it was deleted (beyond the automatic deletion when there's enough downvotes with no answer).

---

The question is relevant to my research and it's important to have it easily accessible.

I believe it to be high quality.

---

The main feedback objections seems to be a matter of *style, not substance*: the notation used and the layout of the thing. It reads better on a mobile than on the main site, I believe; but what does it matter?

Comment: FYI this question was never closed, so there's no need to ask for a reopening. And the deletion was automatic, as per [this criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Answer (score -2):

Please reopen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717365/determinant-equality) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658131/0-a-n1-le-a-n-2-and-b-n2-a-n-b-n1-b-n-prove-b-n-is-boun?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C5.9100).

Both questions was closed because of lacking context, however, the reason I want to reopen both of these questions is that both questions has a score of positive $4$ and $5$, which means it was well-received, even if the OP didn’t show any effort.

I think we must only close these questions once these questions received an answer.

Comment: At that time , questions were loosely upvoted. This did not mean that they were suitable for this site. The questions are definitely off-topic for modern standards , so it would be wrong to reopen them.

Comment: My suggestion would be that if you want to see Answers for such Questions, you ask them again *with the required context*.  After all, your researched interest in them (beyond whatever vote scores they had) should supply a motivation for Readers to respond helpfully.  Of course linking to the old Questions and checking that they have not in meantime been duplicated is a good practice.

Comment: @Peter: The close votes on those two questions took place seven and eight years ago, respectively.  So I think we don't need to doubt the application of "modern standards" in their closure.

Comment: The two questions have now been deleted. It would appear that this was an unintended consequence of drawing attention to them.

Answer (score -4):

Please reopen [Introductory Group theory textbook](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25506).

It's illogical for this to be closed as "opinion-based", when introductory textbook recommendations remain open.

[Books on Number Theory for Layman](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/329)
[Good Book On Combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15201)
[What is the best book to learn probability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31838)

Comment: The three questions you link were all asked twelve years ago, which is like four generations on math.stackexchange. And you've now made them targets for closure....

Comment: Now I've noticed the Group Theory one is also twelve years old (and it was posted by a fellow who was enrolled in my Group Theory course at the time!).

Comment: While I do think book recommendation questions have a place at MSE, but I am unsure about this specific one. The highest-voted answer is about Rotman's book, and I do not think this is a good answer (of course, this is my opinion - see the close reason! - but it does have some extremely complicated content, and for example the pretty standard "classification of f.g. abelian groups" comes after less-standard stuff on Classical and Mathieu groups). Moreover, this question is not going anywhere - it is just closed rather than deleted, and questions can still be closed as a duplicate of it.

Answer (score -6):

Please reopen [Does ‘that is’ (‘i.e.’) mean ‘equivalently’ or ‘so’ or depend on the context?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4776243/21813), whose tag, *article-writing*, goes: “Various aspects of writing mathematics such as style, notation, grammar, frequently used phrases and common mistakes”.

When re-opened, I will post this Answer.

---

Regarding the phrase ‘that is’/‘that is to say’ in the sense of the abbreviation ‘i.e.’, although some of its definitions seem to suggest equivalence, in practice, its logical flow actually runs the gamut:

1. $\boldsymbol\iff$  (*in other words*, *clarification*)

   - Triangle A is equilateral; that is, its sides are of equal length.
   - The sinks of homes with hard water—i.e., a high mineral content—will gradually accumulate white or yellow buildup.
2. $\boldsymbol\implies$  (*elaboration*, *in other words*)

   - Figure A is equilateral triangle; that is, its sides are of equal length.
   - You’ll love how your face feels with the new Guide-n-Glide razor; i.e., it will feel handsome, fresh, and clean.
3. $\boldsymbol\Longleftarrow$  (*clarification*, *elaboration*)

   - One of the intercepts of $(x-3)^2,$ that is, its $x$-intercept, is a minimum point.
   - One meal, i.e., breakfast, is included in the price of the room.

While it is understandable that careful writers wonder whether a sentence like ‘if $P(x),$ then $-2<x<3,$ that is, $|x|<3$’ is technically correct or whether it is peculiar to mathematical writing, the above examples demonstrate that the phrase ‘that is’ (‘i.e.’) has no niche usage that is special to mathematics/technical communication.

In case this phrase's logical meaning is not disambiguated by the context and its ambiguity is not inconsequential, it's worth noting that only Meanings 2 & 3 can unintentionally convey an unintended point.

Comment: The use of "i.e." in math is no different from its use elsewhere in English. It is not a math question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson It is a math question and your first sentence is a possible answer to it.

Comment: There is no reason to assume that the use of "i.e." in maths is different from elsewhere, and the question does not give any evidence towards this. If the answer was "it is different for *these* reasons", or if the question was about how to read a specific sentence which didn't parse with the usual use of i.e. then the question would be reasonable. But as-stated, it could be asking about the use of any random word, like "it" or "these" or "hence", and I cannot see what benefit it brings.

Comment: @user1729 A quibble just with your first sentence: accuracy is particularly valued in mathematical writing, so it is natural for careful writers to wonder about this discrepancy: many dictionaries' explanation of 'i.e.' as [indicating equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations) versus sentences like "figure A is equilateral triangle, i.e., figure A's sides are of equal length" even in mathematics.

Comment: @ryang That isn't an explanation, but an (unhelpful) mnemonic (this is wikipedia and there is no citation for the mnemonic, so it is unclear if anyone actually uses this anyway!). Having now just looked in a few dictionaries, the correct use of i.e. in common English is identical to the correct usage in mathematics, and I have seen no evidence to the contrary. Indeed, apparently the APA style guide states that [all instances of "i.e." be changed to "that is"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48278/that-is-vs-i-e).

Comment: @user1729 Eeeeps, I hadn’t noticed that my previous link was talking about a mnemonic! Anyhow, the point is that most folks will confidently declare that ‘ie’ has the sense of equivalence, which is inconsistent with how this phrase _can_ be used in mathematics; in this view the fact that this phrase *turns out* to not differ in usage between eng & math doesn’t negate the query as mathematically founded; I’d many times asked myself the OP’s exact question, so I believe it is pertinent *and* useful to a subset of mathematics writers.

Comment: Half the readers on, say, ELL.SE having trouble distinguishing among the logical sense of my 3 above example pairs lends credence to why this discussion is not an ill fit for math.SE. Anyhow, here’s a pertinent remark from a previous discussion: “The point is that an outsider would not be able to know a priori whether the term is used just as in natural language or in a technical sense. If it had happened that the word (such as "or") is used in a technical manner, asking someone who is not a mathematician would not lead to the right answer other…

Comment: …than by accident. In this one instance it just so happens that the word does not have a separate mathematical way of being used. But, again, assessing that can essentially only be done from within the community.”

Comment: The question is not a question about mathematical English.  It is a question about English, plain and simple.  The use of "i.e." is no different in mathematics than it is *anywhere else* in the English language.  Math SE is not the right place to have this question answered.  Indeed, there are already many, many answers on [english.se]:  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i.e.%22++site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @ryang I understand what you are saying, and I agree with your point that the phrase turning out "to not differ in usage between eng & math doesn’t negate the query as mathematically founded". However, my point is *there is no reason to assume mathematical usage differs from the "dictionary" definition*. Questions like these should be about clarifying well-founded doubt, not asked on a whim.

Comment: Does anybody know if "i.e." is more frequent in math texts than in non-math ones? I'm not sure how to do that kind of search.

Comment: @user1729 [Regarding the substance of the OP's question, not its suitability for this site] I expanded my Answer to explicitly support (what I infer is) your position that the dictionary definition of 'i.e.' ***is*** compatible with all the three logical senses (`⟺` `⟸` `⟹`).