# How are my two questions considered similar and thus duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I have asked 2 questions. The first is [Lower semi-continuous function attains minimum on a compact set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389350/lower-semi-continuous-function-attains-minimum-on-a-compact-set) and the second is [Characterize lower semi-continuous functions by net convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389475/characterize-lower-semi-continuous-functions-by-net-convergence). The latter has got a total of 4 downvotes (including one from for an answer) and 1 vote to delete.

I could not see how they are similar or duplicate of each other. Could you elaborate on how I got such downvotes?

Comment: Please post the request [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today) instead.

Comment: Meta is not meant for discussing how to improve specific questions.  If you want to know how to improve your question, please use the comments under the question to get advice, or ask for [Constructive Feedback](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to lobby the community for reopening, [we have a thread for that](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today).

Comment: Your first Question is closed as a duplicate of one from last year (by a different user).  Since you seem clear that you posted that first Question in order to provide your own proof, you might consider posting your proof instead as an Answer to the earlier one.  So the premise of your meta Question is a little unclear.  You seem to be interested in proofs that use a net-based definition of convergence (it is mentioned already in your first Question's body, though not in the title).  You have sufficient reputation to participate in the chatroom that Xander pointed you to.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you so much for your elaboration. I have 2 different proofs for 2 different theorems. I would like to ask for a proof verification for each of them. With this goal, I had no choice but to post them separately.