# How can I get my answer's deletion reviewed and possibly overturned

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, deleted-answers

Before posting here, I read these three posts:

1. [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)  which says:

> "For answers, any post that is not an answer (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted."

2. [Can I see my own answer's deletion reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248272/can-i-see-my-own-answers-deletion-reason)
   (My answer has no comment or reason given for deletion that I can see)
3. [What to do when my answer was supposed to be only an alternative to another one, but outvotes it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284256/what-to-do-when-my-answer-was-supposed-to-be-only-an-alternative-to-another-one)
   My answer was in the spirit of what is described here, only that it was not more complicated, but a VERY educational and useful way to get the right answer with a different mathematical path - leading to better overall understanding for students.

### My request for help

My deleted answer is here (not sure if you can see it):
[A circle, a square, and an equilateral triangle had the same area. If their perimeters represent their ages, who are the oldest and the youngest?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473663/a-circle-a-square-and-an-equilateral-triangle-had-the-same-area-if-their-peri/4473945#4473945)

It definitely answers the question, so should not be deleted.

Also, I think it adds correct mathematical understanding, and teaches looking for less obvious ways to get an answer to a question.  The answer is not wrong, and in my opinion it does not dispense poor advice, but that can be subjective - but should only lead to downvotes at worst, according to the rules here.

I would like it undeleted, and ideally some comments from downvoters and for others who are good at math to consider upvoting.

### Background

I have been involved over the years on a few stackexchange sites, off and on, and have over 100 reputation on some of them, so I'm not a troll.  I happened to see this question linked on the RHS of the screen, and thought I'd contribute an outside-the-box thinking answer, as someone well educated in mathematics. As it is a different branch under SE, I had to join as a noob.

I find it disconcerting that 3 people with enough power simply deleted it with no explanation - very quickly it seems.  Based on what I quoted above, I don't think the answer meets the criteria for deletion at all - in fact I don't think it even meets the criteria for downvoting!

The rules say that other people with equivalent power could undelete it.  But I don't see any kind of button or feature to let me "submit for review", or find such people with this power to have a look and decide how to vote.  Is there a way, or if not, could we consider this a new feature?

(edit: this last section seems to be answered by the [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today) that showed up at the top of this page which is pointed to by the "duplicate" tag.  Even though it's not a duplicate, it does seem to ANSWER my question of HOW one would ask for a review - thank you! The only problem is that due to the unfair deletion of my post, I don't have enough reputation to follow the procedure to get the review of the unfair deletion of my post)

Comment: Here's where we are.  The post discussed above was my first post on Math SE, and even though I have decent reputation on some other SE sites, I feel (see above) this one was wrongly deleted and downvoted (with no explanation).  I'd like it reviewed, but because my reputation was hit immediately, I can't even follow the advice and post an answer to the "duplicate" linked at the top, because you need higher reputation to post an answer, which is the way to politely ask for a review.

This is really disappointing, could anyone please help?

Comment: Saying that you approached the Question heuristically and "[j]ust for fun" goes against the resolution of the problem by reasoned mathematical argument and contradicts your asking that the post be undeleted because "[i]t definitely answers the question".  Note that the Question drew answers with mathematical reasoning, consistent with how the OP framed the problem.  Your post may well articulate ideas that you find interesting, but I'd rather you spent time making them rigorous rather than insisting that how one arrives at an answer makes little difference.

Comment: I've voted to reopen because this Question points out a subtle reputation limitation of our canonical mechanism to ask for reconsideration of closing and deletions.  So I think this is worth keeping on our meta site.

Comment: Your answer seems to have been undeleted now.

Comment: One needs points to post an answer on meta? How many?

Comment: @GerryMyerson One needs $5$ reputation points, which I think the user has now (their answer received two upvotes).

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  [Privilege: participate in meta](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) is earned with net reputation of 5 points: "we require a small bit of parent site reputation to prevent spam" may imply that this is exclusive of the *association bonus*.

Comment: @hardmath I have edited out those words.  I felt like they are words a teacher would use as a good way to get into an alternate way of trying to solve a problem.  Perhaps I did not use them correctly.  There is a lot of value to understanding how to approach some mathematical problems the non-obvious way, and it does indeed show mathematical reasoning to arrive at the correct answer, as you have requested.

Comment: The Answer ([on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473663/a-circle-a-square-and-an-equilateral-triangle-had-the-same-area-if-their-peri/4473945#4473945)) has been deleted for a second time.