# Please help me to get some feedback on why my question is closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, close-reasons

Question: [Cases when iteration preserves commutativity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606886/cases-when-iteration-preserves-commutativity)

I don't necessarily object, but I cannot understand why it was downvoted and then closed. This question is really specific. I tried to provide all details at least all I was asked for in the comments. Can someone help so that I will avoid asking poor questions in the future?

Comment: Have you read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question ? and https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions ?

Comment: Sure I did. I am about 6 years in different stackexchange communities, mostly programming. I haven't any problems earlier with understanding why question is closed or downvoted. But this one looks perfectly ok for me. And still...

Comment: Well, I'm convinced. I voted to reopen. If nothing good happens in the next 24 hours, you could consider posting a request to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today

Comment: I don't think I will try to collect reopen votes. Really I had good comment to original question on why is it bad and I think I got it now.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the reddit link it was really useful btw!