# Closure of a question about terminology

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Yesterday I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4623053/572841) about terminology and to my surprise it was closed and downvoted. I would like to understand why. Here is my reasoning:

Usually there are good reasons for the choices of terminology made by mathematicians (even though it is sometimes not obvious from the definition, e.g. right-continuous filtrations) and I think that knowing about these reasons can lead to a better understanding of the topic. So I consider it legitimate to ask questions concerning terminology and in fact the tag [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag was introduced precisely for these type of questions. So the closure seems incoherent to me and most importantly I consider it a pity.

Comment: Maybe it could be useful to clarify whether you're asking about terminology questions in general or about this particular question. (If it is the letter, the tag ([meta-tag:specific-question]) would be suitable here. See also [the tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info).) As a side note, I think you should be able to cast a reopen vote on that question - if you think that it should be reopened. (That should put the question into the reopen review queue.)

Comment: Looking at various tags, the stats for ([tag:terminology]) don't look too bad. [4.43% of non-deleted questions in this tag is closed](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1162425/percentage-of-closed-questions-per-tag?Date1=2000-01-01&Date2=3000-01-01&num=1000) and [17.3% of questions in this tag are deleted](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1251170/percentage-of-deleted-questions-per-tag-only-existing-tags?num=1000).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for the comments. I decided to make it a discussion about my particular question.

Comment: For what it's worth I encountered your question in the review queue this morning and voted to Leave Open as I thought it was well written and asked a pertinent question.  You can post in the Reopen thread (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today ) to ask for it to be reopened

Comment: I feel like the close-vote is a little silly because we have the terminology tag for a reason, but here are my thoughts after reading the edits.

The absolute continuity statement just seems to be how the author defines their notations. If an author defines a certain notation, then you can't really ask much about it. I probably would have voted to close the question after the second edit, though. Your second edit seems to be a separate question, and you seemed to have acknowledged that after getting those 3 close votes.

Comment: ...and I cast the final vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Accelerator Thank you for the feedback. The edit was due to Eric Wofsey's comment, which links to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1695281/572841). To put it into a nutshell, it says that "$P$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $Q$" is (in a particular setting) equivalent to some function being absolutely continuous. This is presumably the reason for this terminology. Since the notation $\ll$ has been abundantly discussed in the comments, I wanted to hear more about this aspect, but the edit was indeed badly received.

Comment: I addition, I thought that the edit would make the question less "opinion-based". Anyways, I once again saw that it is better to make as few edits as possible and ask a new question instead.