# Why my first question was deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, context

My [first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604835/are-there-any-perfect-squares-form-of-1-underbrace22-cdots2-n-text-times5) was deleted more than a year ago.

I will admit that I didn’t give additional context and an effort as at that time, I was very new to the site and I don’t know that it is requirement to give context and clue/effort as much as possible.

In that question, I stated this:

> $1\underbrace{22\cdots2}_{n\text{  times}}5$ is always $1\pmod{4}$ and $4\pmod{11}$.

> $1\underbrace{22\cdots2}_{n\text{  times}}5$ is sometimes divisible by $9$.

Is that considered context/clue.

In my opinion, that question must be undeleted as somehow I give context and clue.

What is the real definition of “context”?

Comment: There is a specific thread ( https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today ) for requests to re-open or undelete questions, which is currently visible on the homepage (with a little bit of scrolling, perhaps).  Your question should be posted in there as it helps organise the site nicely.

Comment: One expected context is the source of the problem. Is that homework? Which book is it from? You have not stated motivation and background and definition. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960