# Why was this question closed for lacking focus?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I posted a question that, in retrospect, was too broad, and it received two votes to close with comments telling me why. I edited it to substantially restrict its scope, and it was upvoted and answered on February 13th. Then today it was closed with the reason "This question needs to be more focused." Why is it considered unfocused in its current form?

The question: [Can you explain how to convert this notation to a function to someone unfamiliar with group theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857338/can-you-explain-how-to-convert-this-notation-to-a-function-to-someone-unfamiliar)

The paper referenced in the question: ["On $C^2$-smooth Surfaces of Constant Width" by Brendan Guilfoyle and Wilhelm Klingenberg](https://sword.cit.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1023&context=dpttem_kpub)

Comment: If you can link a reference to that paper, that would be great.

Comment: @ArcticChar I added a link.

Comment: Oh, I meant adding a link of the paper to the original question (and quote the relevant pages).

Comment: @ArcticChar Done.

Comment: The post has been reopened.

Comment: For future reference, the canonical way to request reopening etc. is [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today) or a more current version of it (generally replaced year to year).