Could someone please explain why was this answer deleted?
Could someone please explain what is wrong with this answer?
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5017532/41841
I've edited to add the trivial syntactical equivalent of what was there all along, I thought. I really don't understand how can the given reason "not an answer" apply there.
How is it "not an answer" if it gives lambda term shorter and simpler than the one in the accepted answer? Yes initially it had it in combinators' syntax, but that's absolutely equivalent to Lambda Calculus.
Why shouldn't it be undeleted?

You will note that the question has been closed. It's possible that the only thing wrong with your answer is that it answered a question several users found to be substandard, and they wanted to discourage answering such questions.

@GerryMyerson thanks. first they downvoted and deleted my answer, then closed the question. Yes, the initial version had only combinatory syntax, but it really is absolutely equivalent to lambda calculus. it's just syntax. I've added the lambda term rendition of the same thing, now, and requested undeletion. this deletion really feels false and bogus to me.

Requests for undeletion should be posted as answers to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today
