# Close as duplicate when the "duplicate" appeared several years later

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, closed-questions

It does not make sense to me that you get your question closed when the duplicate causing it to be closed has appeared many years later.
And the question being closed already has a satisfactory and accepted answer.
I don't get it?
My question asked for pointers to help explain something, then several years later, along comes a question having a proof for a similar question.

So the question having an accepted answer gets closed for the sake of a more difficult to understand proof, that was not requested in the original question.
For my purposes, the explanation was more useful that the proof.

And what does it mean that a question is closed when it is already answered? Does it mean that it will no longer appear in search results?

Can someone point me to a place where the logic behind "close as duplicate" is explained?

Comment: BTW, link to the closed question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625629/square-of-primes-above-5/625645#625645

Comment: [@V.R.M. The best practice is to choose the question which has the best / most answers, or the question which is best posed.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=60934532#60934532)  there was other comments on which he said that the time was not necessarily considered.

Comment: The Help Center has this: [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) You may have a more specific concern, and there are several older Questions linked at right on the Related column.

Comment: Related: [Original post marked as duplicate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16417) (and [other posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/16417)).

Comment: (the logic behind close as duplicate) As with all closed questions, it cannot get new answers. In addition it gains links in a header and on the right side as a linked question, so that anyone who finds the question in the future can easily find the web of linked resources that answer the question.  In effect the closed question becomes a redirect to help people find the already existing answers.  Chronological appearance takes a back seat to putting the best information in front of the reader.  Existing answers go on, but further answers get channeled to the open counterparts.

Comment: _what does it mean that a question is closed when it is already answered?_  This is uttered as if the existing answer should prevent closure, inviting further answers and not connecting it to the relevant existing answers. What is the logic in any of that?

Comment: It might help to stop thinking of it as your question, but instead think of it as the web site's question. I know that individual users retain a lot of rights to their content, but decisions on how or if to display the question are decided based on how to create the best web site*, not on how to best benefit any individual user. (*There is lots of debate as to what makes the best web site, and how to best encourage volunteer members to create it, but that's a separate point.)

Comment: thanks all , very helpful